# How to determine the encoding of text

Tags: python, encoding, text-files

I received some text that is encoded, but I don't know what charset was used. Is there a way to determine the encoding of a text file using Python? [How can I detect the encoding/codepage of a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file) deals with C#.

Answer (score 284, accepted):

EDIT: chardet seems to be unmantained but most of the answer applies. Check https://pypi.org/project/charset-normalizer/ for an alternative

Correctly detecting the encoding all times is **impossible**.

(From chardet FAQ:)

> However, some encodings are optimized
> for specific languages, and languages
> are not random. Some character
> sequences pop up all the time, while
> other sequences make no sense. A
> person fluent in English who opens a
> newspaper and finds “txzqJv 2!dasd0a
> QqdKjvz” will instantly recognize that
> that isn't English (even though it is
> composed entirely of English letters).
> By studying lots of “typical” text, a
> computer algorithm can simulate this
> kind of fluency and make an educated
> guess about a text's language.

There is the [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) library that uses that study to try to detect encoding. chardet is a port of the auto-detection code in Mozilla.

You can also use [UnicodeDammit](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit). It will try the following methods:

- An encoding discovered in the document itself: for instance, in an XML declaration or (for HTML documents) an http-equiv META tag. If Beautiful Soup finds this kind of encoding within the document, it parses the document again from the beginning and gives the new encoding a try. The only exception is if you explicitly specified an encoding, and that encoding actually worked: then it will ignore any encoding it finds in the document.
- An encoding sniffed by looking at the first few bytes of the file. If an encoding is detected at this stage, it will be one of the UTF-* encodings, EBCDIC, or ASCII.
- An encoding sniffed by the [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) library, if you have it installed.
- UTF-8
- Windows-1252

Comment: Thanks for the `chardet` reference. Seems good, although a bit slow.

Comment: Not been able to detect the encoding all the time...isn't this a flaw in the encoding standard? shouldn't this be allways predictable?

Comment: @Geomorillo: There's no such thing as "the encoding standard". Text encoding is something as old as computing, it grew organically with time and needs, it wasn't planned. "Unicode" is an attempt to fix this.

Comment: And not a bad one, all things considered. What I would like to know is, how do I find out what encoding an open text file was opened with?

Comment: I am confused by this. I have a text file I was struggling to read in Python, so I opened it in Visual Studio Code. In the bottom gutter of the resulting file window it says "UTF-16 LE". When you note that it is impossible does that means that tools like VSCode would fail too?

Comment: @dumbledad what I said is that correctly detecting it **all times** is impossible. All you can do is a guess, but it can fail sometimes, it won't work every time, due to encodings not being really detectable. To do the guess, you can use one of the tools I suggested in the answer

Comment: `chardet` has some really nice command line interface, i'm not sure about your use case, for me i was really just trying to guess a file charset on-the-fly, and not to use that in a script or something.
to use the CLI option (after `pip install chardet`)
`$ chardet filename`
and you can use the guessed encoding to encode your text file into other options, using tools like `iconv`.

Comment: I'd love `chardet` but since Turkish support was added it skewed numbers in a way that now it guesses Turkish for way too many files I came across. So much so I had to get rid of `chardet`.

Comment: Apparently `cchardet` is faster, but requires `cython`.

Comment: @LasseKärkkäinen the point of that answer is to show that corectly detecting encoding is **impossible**; the function you provide can guess right for your case, but is wrong for many cases.

Comment: @nosklo Quite true; that's why the comment says 8-bit guesswork. However, sensible priorities should be used and now chardet favours Turkish way too much. The paste demonstrates clear problems with chardet that cannot be justified by the ambiguity (because \x81 does not exist in the "detected" encoding and because UTF-8 should always be the first choice whenever it fits).

Comment: You could add the more recent [charset-normalizer](https://pypi.org/project/charset-normalizer/)

Comment: Impossible? You mean lack of knowledge? Face ID for face recognition, Shazam for sound works very well, but charset detection is impossible.. interesting.

Comment: @Cyborg when the same bytes can mean different things on different encodings, it is impossible to make it work **all times**; please read the entire sentence

Comment: @Cyborg the difference between solving a problem in 100% vs 98% of cases is huge in terms of how the software can be used. Charset detection is just like the examples you mention impossible to get to 100.

Answer (score 99):

Another option for working out the encoding is to use
[libmagic](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libmagic) (which is the code behind the
[file](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command). There are a profusion of
python bindings available.

The python bindings that live in the file source tree are available as the
[python-magic](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-magic&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) (or [python3-magic](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3-magic&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all))
debian package. It can determine the encoding of a file by doing:

```python
import magic

blob = open('unknown-file', 'rb').read()
m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_MIME_ENCODING)
m.load()
encoding = m.buffer(blob)  # "utf-8" "us-ascii" etc
```

There is an identically named, but incompatible, [python-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic) pip package on pypi that also uses `libmagic`. It can also get the encoding, by doing:

```python
import magic

blob = open('unknown-file', 'rb').read()
m = magic.Magic(mime_encoding=True)
encoding = m.from_buffer(blob)
```

Comment: `libmagic` is indeed a viable alternative to `chardet`. And great info on the distinct packages named `python-magic`! I'm sure this ambiguity bites many people

Comment: `file` isn't particularly good at identifying human language in text files.  It is excellent for identifying various container formats, though you sometimes have to know what it means ("Microsoft Office document" could mean an Outlook message, etc).

Comment: Looking for a way to manage file encoding mystery I found this post. Unfortunately, using the example code, I can't get past `open()`: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 169799: invalid start byte`. The file encoding according to vim's `:set fileencoding` is `latin1`.

Comment: If I use the optional argument `errors='ignore'`, the output of the example code is the less helpful `binary`.

Comment: @xtian You need to open in binary mode, i.e. open("filename.txt", "rb").

Comment: chardet didn't work for `iso-8859-1` (a common Windows file format), but this works perfectly! libmagic seems like the best solution to this problem.

Comment: the second one solved my problem. And I have to use blob = open("unknown-file", "rb").read() like L. Kärkkäinen said.

Comment: There's also a python-magic-bin package which has binaries and works on Windows: https://github.com/julian-r/python-magic 

That package returned 'binary' for the encoding for a .docx file, while UnicodeDammit returned 'utf-8' and chardet returned None. In this case, bs4 (UnicodeDammit) looks best.

Comment: I'm getting the error `module 'magic' has no attribute 'open'`. I don't think there is a magic.open() function?

Answer (score 45):

Some encoding strategies, please uncomment to taste :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#
tmpfile=$1
echo '-- info about file file ........'
file -i $tmpfile
enca -g $tmpfile
echo 'recoding ........'
#iconv -f iso-8859-2 -t utf-8 back_test.xml > $tmpfile
#enca -x utf-8 $tmpfile
#enca -g $tmpfile
recode CP1250..UTF-8 $tmpfile
```

You might like to check the encoding by opening and reading the file in a form of a loop... but you might need to check the filesize first :

```py
# PYTHON
encodings = ['utf-8', 'windows-1250', 'windows-1252'] # add more
for e in encodings:
    try:
        fh = codecs.open('file.txt', 'r', encoding=e)
        fh.readlines()
        fh.seek(0)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print('got unicode error with %s , trying different encoding' % e)
    else:
        print('opening the file with encoding:  %s ' % e)
        break
```

Comment: You can also use `io`, like `io.open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')`, which is more convenient, because `codecs` doesn't convert `\n` automatically on reading and writing. More on [HERE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open)

Answer (score 41):

Here is an example of reading and taking at face value a `chardet` encoding prediction, reading `n_lines` from the file in the event it is large.

`chardet` also gives you a probability (i.e. `confidence`) of it's encoding prediction (haven't looked how they come up with that), which is returned with its prediction from `chardet.predict()`, so you could work that in somehow if you like.

```
import chardet
from pathlib import Path

def predict_encoding(file_path: Path, n_lines: int=20) -> str:
    '''Predict a file's encoding using chardet'''

    # Open the file as binary data
    with Path(file_path).open('rb') as f:
        # Join binary lines for specified number of lines
        rawdata = b''.join([f.readline() for _ in range(n_lines)])

    return chardet.detect(rawdata)['encoding']
```

Comment: Looking at this after getting an up-vote and now see that this solution could slow down if there were a lot of data on the first line. In some cases it would be better to read the data in differently.

Comment: I have modified this function this way:

  
`def predict_encoding(file_path, n=20):  
... skip ... and then  
rawdata = b''.join([f.read() for _ in range(n)])`
  
Have been tried this function on Python 3.6, worked perfectly with "ascii", "cp1252", "utf-8", "unicode" encodings. So this is definitely upvote.

Comment: this is very good for handling small datasets with a variety of formats. Tested this recursively on my root dir and it worked like a treat. Thanks buddy.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with reading data at the byte level. @n158, is there a chance one might stop reading bytes in the middle of a character and confuse `chardet`?

Comment: Of all the great suggestions, I found this the most useful.  I also include @n158 suggestion to only read 20 bytes instead of 20 lines.

Answer (score 19):

This might be helpful

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit
with open('automate_data/billboard.csv', 'rb') as file:
   content = file.read()

suggestion = UnicodeDammit(content)
suggestion.original_encoding
#'iso-8859-1'
```

Comment: Thank you, I could determine the correct encoding now!

Comment: UnicodeDammit ought to be added to the standard library imo.

Answer (score 9):

If you are not satisfied with the automatic tools you can try all codecs and see which codec is right manually.

```
all_codecs = ['ascii', 'big5', 'big5hkscs', 'cp037', 'cp273', 'cp424', 'cp437', 
'cp500', 'cp720', 'cp737', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857', 
'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 
'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932', 'cp949', 'cp950', 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1125', 
'cp1140', 'cp1250', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'cp1253', 'cp1254', 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 
'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'euc_jp', 'euc_jis_2004', 'euc_jisx0213', 'euc_kr', 
'gb2312', 'gbk', 'gb18030', 'hz', 'iso2022_jp', 'iso2022_jp_1', 'iso2022_jp_2', 
'iso2022_jp_2004', 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'iso2022_kr', 'latin_1', 
'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 
'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_11', 'iso8859_13', 
'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'johab', 'koi8_r', 'koi8_t', 'koi8_u', 
'kz1048', 'mac_cyrillic', 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2', 'mac_roman', 
'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004', 'shift_jisx0213', 
'utf_32', 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_be', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_7', 
'utf_8', 'utf_8_sig']

def find_codec(text):
    for i in all_codecs:
        for j in all_codecs:
            try:
                print(i, "to", j, text.encode(i).decode(j))
            except:
                pass

find_codec("The example string which includes ö, ü, or ÄŸ, Ã¶")
```

This script creates at least 9409 lines of output. So, if the output cannot fit to the terminal screen try to write the output to a text file.

Comment: As a complement to this good answer, I wrote a [Python script](https://gist.github.com/FilipDominec/912b18147842ed5de7adbf3fab1413c9) that prints out a nice table of possible encoding mismatches, provided a small sample of the original correct string is guessed by users. Then, it suggests which encode/decode pair undoes the mismatch.

Comment: Thanks. Thru trial and error, I was finally able to get a SQL Server table with collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to emit data into a CSV using utf_8_sig.. It's a useful list of encodings (via Python/SQLAlchemy/PYODBC) ... So now Noël for example displays.

Answer (score 6):

```
# Function: OpenRead(file)

# A text file can be encoded using:
#   (1) The default operating system code page, Or
#   (2) utf8 with a BOM header
#
#  If a text file is encoded with utf8, and does not have a BOM header,
#  the user can manually add a BOM header to the text file
#  using a text editor such as notepad++, and rerun the python script,
#  otherwise the file is read as a codepage file with the 
#  invalid codepage characters removed

import sys
if int(sys.version[0]) != 3:
    print('Aborted: Python 3.x required')
    sys.exit(1)

def bomType(file):
    """
    returns file encoding string for open() function

    EXAMPLE:
        bom = bomtype(file)
        open(file, encoding=bom, errors='ignore')
    """

    f = open(file, 'rb')
    b = f.read(4)
    f.close()

    if (b[0:3] == b'\xef\xbb\xbf'):
        return "utf8"

    # Python automatically detects endianess if utf-16 bom is present
    # write endianess generally determined by endianess of CPU
    if ((b[0:2] == b'\xfe\xff') or (b[0:2] == b'\xff\xfe')):
        return "utf16"

    if ((b[0:5] == b'\xfe\xff\x00\x00') 
              or (b[0:5] == b'\x00\x00\xff\xfe')):
        return "utf32"

    # If BOM is not provided, then assume its the codepage
    #     used by your operating system
    return "cp1252"
    # For the United States its: cp1252


def OpenRead(file):
    bom = bomType(file)
    return open(file, 'r', encoding=bom, errors='ignore')


#######################
# Testing it
#######################
fout = open("myfile1.txt", "w", encoding="cp1252")
fout.write("* hi there (cp1252)")
fout.close()

fout = open("myfile2.txt", "w", encoding="utf8")
fout.write("\u2022 hi there (utf8)")
fout.close()

# this case is still treated like codepage cp1252
#   (User responsible for making sure that all utf8 files
#   have a BOM header)
fout = open("badboy.txt", "wb")
fout.write(b"hi there.  barf(\x81\x8D\x90\x9D)")
fout.close()

# Read Example file with Bom Detection
fin = OpenRead("myfile1.txt")
L = fin.readline()
print(L)
fin.close()

# Read Example file with Bom Detection
fin = OpenRead("myfile2.txt")
L =fin.readline() 
print(L) #requires QtConsole to view, Cmd.exe is cp1252
fin.close()

# Read CP1252 with a few undefined chars without barfing
fin = OpenRead("badboy.txt")
L =fin.readline() 
print(L)
fin.close()

# Check that bad characters are still in badboy codepage file
fin = open("badboy.txt", "rb")
fin.read(20)
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

It is, in principle, impossible to determine the encoding of a text file, in the general case. So no, there is no standard Python library to do that for you.

If you have more specific knowledge about the text file (e.g. that it is XML), there might be library functions.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your platform, I just opt to use the linux shell `file` command. This works for me since I am using it in a script that exclusively runs on one of our linux machines.

Obviously this isn't an ideal solution or answer, but it could be modified to fit your needs. In my case I just need to determine whether a file is UTF-8 or not.

```
import subprocess
file_cmd = ['file', 'test.txt']
p = subprocess.Popen(file_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd_output = p.stdout.readlines()
# x will begin with the file type output as is observed using 'file' command
x = cmd_output[0].split(": ")[1]
return x.startswith('UTF-8')
```

Comment: Forking a new process is not needed. Python code already runs inside a process, and can call the proper system functions itself without the overhead of loading a new process.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the some content of the file you can try to decode it with several encoding and see which is missing. In general there is no way since a text file is a text file and those are stupid ;)

Answer (score 1):

This site has python code for recognizing ascii, encoding with boms, and utf8 no bom:  https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/guess_encoding.html.  Read file into byte array (data):  http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Read_a_file_into_a_byte_array.  Here's an example.  I'm in osx.

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                  

import sys

def isUTF8(data):
    try:
        decoded = data.decode('UTF-8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return False
    else:
        for ch in decoded:
            if 0xD800 <= ord(ch) <= 0xDFFF:
                return False
        return True

def get_bytes_from_file(filename):
    return open(filename, "rb").read()

filename = sys.argv[1]
data = get_bytes_from_file(filename)
result = isUTF8(data)
print(result)


PS /Users/js> ./isutf8.py hi.txt                                                                                     
True
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Using linux `file -i`  command

```
import subprocess

file = "path/to/file/file.txt"

encoding =  subprocess.Popen("file -bi "+file, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout

encoding = re.sub(r"(\\n)[^a-z0-9\-]", "", str(encoding.read()).split("=")[1], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    
print(encoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python-magic package which does not load the whole file to memory:

```py
import magic


def detect(
    file_path,
):
    return magic.Magic(
        mime_encoding=True,
    ).from_file(file_path)
```

The output is the encoding name for example:

- iso-8859-1
- us-ascii
- utf-8

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chardet module

```
import chardet

with open (filepath , "rb") as f:
    data= f.read()
    encode=chardet.UniversalDetector()
    encode.close()
    print(encode.result)
```

Or you can use the chardet3 command in linux but it takes a few time :

```
chardet3 fileName
```

Example :

```
chardet3 donnee/dir/donnee.csv
donnee/dir/donnee.csv: ISO-8859-1 with confidence 0.73
```

Comment: The python code does nothing, `data` variable is not used, it should be returning something like this: `return chardet.detect(data)` but is slow as hell, more info [here](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-using-the-detect-function)

Answer (score 0):

Some text files are aware of their encoding, most are not. Aware:

- a text file having a BOM
- an XML file is encoded in UTF-8 or its encoding is given in the preamble
- a JSON file is always encoded in UTF-8

Not aware:

- a CSV file
- any random text file

Some encodings are versatile, ie they can decode any sequence of bytes, some are not. US-ASCII is not versatile, since any byte greater than 127 is not mapped to any character. UTF-8 is not versatile since any sequence of bytes is not valid.

On the contrary, Latin-1, Windows-1252, etc. are versatile (even if some bytes are not officially mapped to a character):

```
>>> [b.to_bytes(1, 'big').decode("latin-1") for b in range(256)]
['\x00', ..., 'ÿ']
```

Given a random text file encoded in a sequence of bytes, you can't determine the encoding unless the file is aware of its encoding, because some encodings are versatile. But you can sometimes exclude non versatile encodings. All versatile encodings are still possible. The `chardet` modules uses the frequency of bytes to guess which encoding fits the best to the encoded text.

If you don't want to use this module or a similar one, here's a simple method:

- check if the file is aware of its encoding (BOM)
- check non versatile encodings and accept the first that can decode the bytes  (ASCII before UTF-8 because it is stricter)
- choose a fallback encoding.

*The second step is a bit risky if you check only a sample, because some bytes in the rest of the file may be invalid.*

The code:

```
def guess_encoding(data: bytes, fallback: str = "iso8859_15") -> str:
    """
    A basic encoding detector.
    """
    for bom, encoding in [
        (codecs.BOM_UTF32_BE, "utf_32_be"),
        (codecs.BOM_UTF32_LE, "utf_32_le"),
        (codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE, "utf_16_be"),
        (codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE, "utf_16_le"),
        (codecs.BOM_UTF8, "utf_8_sig"),
    ]:
        if data.startswith(bom):
            return encoding

    if all(b < 128 for b in data):
        return "ascii"  # you may want to use the fallback here if data is only a sample.

    decoder = codecs.getincrementaldecoder("utf_8")()
    try:
        decoder.decode(data, final=False)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return fallback
    else:
        return "utf_8"  # not certain if data is only a sample
```

Remember that non versatile encoding may fail. The `errors` parameter of the `decode` method can be set to `'ignore'` , `'replace'` or `'backslashreplace'` to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago, I had this need.

Reading old code of mine, I found this:

```
    import urllib.request
    import chardet
    import os
    import settings

    [...]
    file = 'sources/dl/file.csv'
    media_folder = settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    file = os.path.join(media_folder, str(file))
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        file_2_test = urllib.request.urlopen('file://' + file).read()
        encoding = (chardet.detect(file_2_test))['encoding']
        return encoding
```

This worked for me and returned `ascii`

Answer (score 0):

[With this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16203777/9409770)

I just want to add, for everyone's information, to install magic from the Python 3 pip:

```
pip install python-magic
```

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76639562/9409770)
[Reference 2](https://pypi.org/project/python-magic/)