# Detect charset and convert to utf-8 in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.x

Is there any universal method to detect string charset? I user IPTC tags and have no known encoding. I need to detect it and then change them to utf-8.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Looking at your comment to @Ignacio, I would invite you to paste a couple of examples of "None" string into your question, so that we can play around with them and understand what the issue is. It would be helpful if you could also paste their correct decoded version as done on the portal you mentioned.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You want to use [`chardet`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet), an encoding detector

Comment: It doesn't work, I trierd it before asking here. Some strings get None encoding but it's not true. Tags are encoded somehow because on 1 web portal they are recognized.

Comment: +1: chardet seems to be one of the best current ways of doing encoding detection.  @robos85: It is not possible to do a perfect encoding detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file/436299#436299.

Comment: I have developed a much more successful way of detecting the encoding, based on knowing the language.  It gets the 8-bit encodings right.  Finally.

Comment: @tchrist: care to share?

Answer (score 18):

It's a bit late, but there is also another solution: try to use [pyicu](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU/0.8.1).

An example:

```
import icu
def convert_encoding(data, new_coding='UTF-8'):
    coding = icu.CharsetDetector(data).detect().getName()
    if new_coding.upper() != coding.upper():
        data = unicode(data, coding).encode(new_coding)
    return data
```

Comment: pyicu based on icu, and sometimes will miss-detect some encoding: http://sourceforge.net/p/icu/mailman/icu-design/thread/OFC8C84672.06B930B4-ON85257BDC.005E1362-85257BDC.005DE5A0@lotus.com/

Comment: @coanor: *any* encoding detector will fail in some cases, as there is no way to accurately determine the encoding for all tests

Answer (score 17):

If you want to do it with cchardet, you can use this function.

```
import cchardet
def convert_encoding(data, new_coding = 'UTF-8'):
  encoding = cchardet.detect(data)['encoding']

  if new_coding.upper() != encoding.upper():
    data = data.decode(encoding, data).encode(new_coding)

  return data
```

Comment: I tried many encoding format (base64, ... ) . the result is always ascii

Answer (score 5):

There is another module called [cchardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cchardet/0.3.5)

It is said to be faster than chardet.

Note that it requires [Cython](http://www.cython.org/)