# How to detect string byte encoding?

Tags: python, string, unicode, encoding, byte

I've got about 1000 filenames read by `os.listdir()`, some of them are encoded in UTF8 and some are CP1252.

I want to decode all of them to Unicode for further processing in my script. Is there a way to get the source encoding to correctly decode into Unicode?

Example:

```
for item in os.listdir(rootPath):

    #Convert to Unicode
    if isinstance(item, str):
        item = item.decode('cp1252')  # or item = item.decode('utf-8')
    print item
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

if your files either in `cp1252` and `utf-8`, then there is an easy way.

```
import logging
def force_decode(string, codecs=['utf8', 'cp1252']):
    for i in codecs:
        try:
            return string.decode(i)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass

    logging.warn("cannot decode url %s" % ([string]))

for item in os.listdir(rootPath):
    #Convert to Unicode
    if isinstance(item, str):
        item = force_decode(item)
    print item
```

otherwise, there is a charset detect lib.

[Python - detect charset and convert to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707657/python-detect-charset-and-convert-to-utf-8)

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet

Answer (score 74):

Use chardet library. It is super easy

```
import chardet

the_encoding = chardet.detect('your string')['encoding']
```

and that's it!

in python3 you need to provide type bytes or bytearray so:

```
import chardet
the_encoding = chardet.detect(b'your string')['encoding']
```

Comment: Seems to me it doesnt work. I have created string variable and encoded it utf-8.  chardet returned TIS-620  encoding.

Comment: I found that cchardet appears to be the current name for this or a similar library...; chardet was not findable.

Comment: A bit confused here. It seems like it isn't possible to provide an str class as an argument. Only b'your string' works for me, or directly providing a byte variable.

Comment: The problem with this answer for me is that some cp1252/latin1 characters can be interpreted as technically valid utf8 - which leads to `Ãª` type characters where it should have been `ê`. `chardet` seems to try utf8 first, which results in this. There may be a way to tell it which order to use, but [lucemia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15918519/623519) worked better for me.

Comment: ↑ sorry, I think I got utf8 and cp1252 the wrong way round in my description in last comment!

Comment: In Python 3: `TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 'str'>`

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You need to provide a byte string or bytearray, not a string to decode.

Comment: `>>> chardet.detect("ö".encode())` and `{'encoding': 'TIS-620', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': 'Thai'}` — I'd say that doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

You also can use `json` package to detect encoding.

```
import json

json.detect_encoding(b"Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with both json and chardet, and I got these results:

```
import json
import chardet

data = b'\xa9 2023'
json.detect_encoding(data)  # 'utf-8'
data.decode('utf-8')  # UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 0: invalid start byte

chardet.detect(data)  # {'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
data.decode("ISO-8859-1")  # '© 2023'
```

Answer (score 1):

**charset_normalizer** is a drop in replacement for **chardet**.

It works better on natural language and has a permissive MIT licence: https://github.com/Ousret/charset_normalizer/

```py
from charset_normalizer import detect
encoding = detect(byte_string)['encoding']
```

PS: This is not strictly related to the original question but this page comes up in Google a lot

Answer (score 0):

`chardet` detected encoding can be used to decode an bytearray without any exception, but the output string may not be correct.

The `try ... except ...` way works perfectly for known encodings, but it does not work for all scenarios.

We can use `try ... except ...` first and then `chardet` as plan B:

```py
    def decode(byte_array: bytearray, preferred_encodings: List[str] = None):
        if preferred_encodings is None:
            preferred_encodings = [
                'utf8',       # Works for most cases
                'cp1252'      # Other encodings may appear in your project
            ]

        for encoding in preferred_encodings:
            # Try preferred encodings first
            try:
                return byte_array.decode(encoding)
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass
        else:
            # Use detected encoding
            encoding = chardet.detect(byte_array)['encoding']
            return byte_array.decode(encoding)
```