# (Python) byte data to string conversion

Tags: python, arrays, encoding

(Python)I have data in bytes,

```
b'\x03H\x8c\xec\x10\xf14~0F\x93\xe9Q&xZ\x054n\x9aa3+!\xa6B\xce\xef\x96\x9f\x80o-\xfb\xf4\x81\xe0\xa2\x96\x0cE\xa4D\xe6\x10\x9d\xb3\x12\r\xda\xfe\x00d*\xee;\xcekz`y\xe8\xd3{'
```

And I am told this is its string representation, and I am suspecting this is a hex string.

```
fd2bc562a95c4924d27f9f81de052fbab650f0c2989ee9f4e826244e7c1f0e66
```

Does anyone know how to find the encoding for the bytes?

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918314/how-to-detect-string-byte-encoding

Comment: No, chardet does not work in my case. It returns None as the encoding.

Comment: This isn't UTF-8 nor UTF-16, nor either of the two popular Chinese pre-Unicode encodings (Big5, Guobiao). Try to find out more from the person who gave this problem to you.

Comment: Thanks for checking. Unfortunately the only information I have is this is a string of a hash.