# decode a string to recognize french characters

Tags: python, utf-8, decode, python-3.6

how to decode a string to recognize french characters in python
example 'Pneus Ã©tÃ©' should be like 'Pneus été'

I tried this but it appears that does not work

```
var ='Pneus Ã©tÃ©'
print(var.decode('utf-8'))
```

**this is my original code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import math
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import helpers
import os
if __name__== '__main__':
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(os.getcwd()+"/Desktop/Pneus auto _ Michelin FR.html"), 'html.parser')
    tyre_category = soup.find_all('div', class_='tyre')
    for category in tyre_category:
        tyre_name = category.img['alt']
        tyre_season = category.find('span', class_='season-icon')['title']
        url_for_tyre_details = category.find('a', class_='tyre-detail')['href']

        print(tyre_name, tyre_season, url_for_tyre_details, sep=",")
```

OUTPUT:

```
MICHELIN Primacy 4,Pneus Ã©tÃ©,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-primacy-4
MICHELIN Pilot Sport 4,Pneus Ã©tÃ©,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-pilot-sport-4
MICHELIN Pilot Sport 4 S,Pneus Ã©tÃ©,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-pilot-sport-4-s
MICHELIN Pilot Sport Cup 2,Pneus Ã©tÃ©,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-pilot-sport-cup-2
MICHELIN CrossClimate+,toutes saisons,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-crossclimateplus
MICHELIN Alpin 6,Pneus Hiver,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-alpin-6
MICHELIN Pilot Alpin 5,Pneus Hiver,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-pilot-alpin-5
MICHELIN Pilot Alpin PA4,Pneus Hiver,https://www.michelin.fr/pneus/michelin-pilot-alpin-pa4
```

*please note that the variable **tyre_season** get's printed like this 'Pneus Ã©tÃ©' and i wanted to be like that 'Pneus été'*

Comment: Well, that string doesn't contain French accented characters. It contains [garbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). How did that string get like this in the first place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - detect charset and convert to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707657/python-detect-charset-and-convert-to-utf-8)

Comment: in fact, I tried to scrape a webpage and when I wanted to grab this sentence "Pneus été" and print it, I am getting this "Pneus Ã©tÃ©" and I would like to get the correct sentence.  @GiacomoCatenazziv

Comment: You’re just opening the file using the wrong/unspecified encoding.

Comment: add an `ecoding='utf-8'` named parameter to the `open` call, should do.

Comment: `soup = BeautifulSoup(open(os.getcwd()+"/Desktop/Pneus auto _ Michelin FR.html", encoding='utf-8'), 'lxml')`  <br/> **this works for me**

Comment: Would you like to accept my answer then? Great to know it solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

What your string in the question contains is the UTF-8 representation of the unicode string `Pneus été`. You can try this like so:

```
s = 'Pneus été'
s.encode(encoding='utf-8')
```

This results in the encoded bytes `b'Pneus \xc3\xa9t\xc3\xa9'`

Or the other way round: if you take the bytes and decode them as UTF-8:

```
s = b'Pneus \xC3\xA9t\xC3\xA9'
s.decode('utf-8')
```

You get: `'Pneus été'` as unicode string.

So, somewhere in your code you have read a unicode string without proper decoding.

Comment: in fact, I tried to scrape a webpage and when I wanted to grab this sentence "Pneus été" and print it, I am getting this "Pneus Ã©tÃ©", why that happens

Comment: Please post how you read the response from the webserver, lokks like this the place where the encoding get wrangled.

Comment: `if __name__== '__main__':
 soup = BeautifulSoup(open("C:/Users/usrname/Desktop/Pneus auto _ Michelin FR.html"), 'lxml')
 tyre_category = soup.find_all('div', class_='tyre')
 for category in tyre_category:
  tyre_name = category.img['alt']
  tyre_season = category.find('span', class_='season-icon')['title']
  url_for_tyre_details = category.find('a', class_='tyre-detail')['href']

 print(tyre_name, tyre_season, url_for_tyre_details, sep=",")
 print()`####################
 
 
please check the formatted code above