# Find out the unicode script of a character

Tags: python, unicode

Given a unicode character what would be the simplest way to return its [script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unicode%29) (as  "Latin", "Hangul" etc)? [unicodedata](http://docs.python.org/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata) doesn't seem to provide this kind of feature.

Comment: What do you mean by "script value"?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file . The link says that correctly detecting the encoding always is impossible.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28Unicode%29

Comment: phaedrus, they're not trying to detect how the codepoint is encoded, just which writing system it's from (hence "Latin", "Hangul") which is do-able so long as you're happy to accept either a vague answer or none for some codepoints.

Comment: @phaedrus: I understand that that question is not about detecting encodings, but about what is called the "standardized subsets" of Unicode. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Standardized_subsets.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was hoping someone's done it before, but apparently not, so here's what I've ended up with. The module below (I call it `unicodedata2`) extends `unicodedata` and provides `script_cat(chr)` which returns a tuple (Script name, Category) for a unicode char. Example:

```
# coding=utf8
import unicodedata2
print unicodedata2.script_cat(u'Ф')  #('Cyrillic', 'L')
print unicodedata2.script_cat(u'の')  #('Hiragana', 'Lo')
print unicodedata2.script_cat(u'★')  #('Common', 'So')
```

The module: https://gist.github.com/2204527

Comment: @EOL: just out of curiosity, what's the point of your edit? I'm no emacs user, so I'm not sure what these `-*-` are good for.

Comment: @thg435: Good question: I thought that the `-*-` syntax was a general Python convention, but then I checked PEP 263 and discovered it was not. :)  I mostly reverted the change (the new version reflects PEP 263 better, though). I did a space before the comment mark `#`, so as to follow the "at least two spaces" PEP 8 convention (reference: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments).

Comment: @thg, would you consider modifying your gist to add a liberal open source license like BSD or MIT? I'd like to include it in my project, but it's enough code that I don't feel comfortable doing that unlicensed.

Comment: @Reid: this one is not referred to elsewhere and is an integral part of my post and thus, as all contributions to SO, is [licensed under CC](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing) by default.

Comment: Great work!  And thanks for providing that under CC (i.e. CC-by-sa). But that is problematic for code, and CC says to use either MIT, GPL or LGPL.  See e.g. a lot of headaches discussed here: http://wiki.creativecommons.org/GPL_compatibility_use_cases  So please pick one of those programming licenses and let us use that.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks a lot! How do you know that all those numbers in the code are correct?

Comment: Have you had a chance to consider licensing your code under the MIT license or similar please? Please see @nealmcb's comment above as to why plain CC-by-sa is problematic for code.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the Python unicodedata module contains tools for accessing the main file in the Unicode database but nothing for the other files: “The data in this database is based on the UnicodeData.txt file”

The script information is in the [Scripts.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt) file. It is of relatively simple format (described in [UAX #44](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/)) and not horribly large (131 kilobytes), so you might consider parsing it in your program. Note that in the Unicode classification, there’s the “Common” script that contains characters used in different scripts, like punctuation marks.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of is unfortunately to get the Unicode code point with `ord()` and then use your own  table (by using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Standardized_subsets and more). A preliminary conversion to some normal form may be in order, so as to handle the fact that a single "written" character can be expressed with different sequences of code points (the unicodedata module helps, here).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ord` to retrieve the numeric value of a character (it works on both unicode and byte strings of length 1).

The next step, unfortunately, will involve you then testing against the ranges. Possibly the data here will be of assistance: http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Oftentimes it is just enough to detect if a certain script is used, and then you can use the `unicodedata.name` with prefix matching. For example to find out whether a letter is Cyrillic, you can use

```
class CharacterNamePrefixTester(dict):
    def __init__(self, prefix):
        self.prefix = prefix
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = unicodedata.name(key, '').startswith(self.prefix)
        return self[key]

>>> cyrillic = CharaterNamePrefixTester('CYRILLIC ')
>>> cyrillic['й']
True
>>> cyrillic['a']
False
```

The dictionary is built lazily but the truth values are memoized so that future lookups of the same letter will be faster.

Comment: yes, good idea, however there are names like 'COMBINING CYRILLIC whatever'

Answer (score 0):

You can detect it with the new Python library that identifies the writing system of text based on [ISO 15924](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924): https://github.com/cisnlp/GlotScript.

It uses the `ord` function to obtain the Unicode code point, as Eric O. Lebigot's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9868938/16478538) indicates, and uses the ranges for each script from Scripts.txt, as Jukka K. Korpela's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9871217/16478538) points out. In the case of code-switching, it provides you with all of the scripts involved along with their percentage distribution.

```bash
pip3 install GlotScript
```

```py
from GlotScript import sp

sp('これは日本人です')
# ('Hira', 0.625, {'details': {'Hira': 0.625, 'Hani': 0.375}, 'tie': False, 'interval': 0.25})


sp('This is Latin')[:1]
# ('Latn', 1.0)

sp('මේක සිංහල')[0]
# 'Sinh'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but I wish to give a slightly more comprehensive answer. And provide examples using to different modules: *PyICU* and *Unicodedataplus*, a drop-in replacement for *unicodedata*.

Unicode has two relevant character properties:

1. script - an ISO 15924 script code for the character
2. script extensions - a list of one, or more scripts when a character can be used with more than one script.

ISO 15924 defines codes for scripts. But there are a range of special script codes, including:

- `Zinh` Code for inherited script (*Inherited*)
- `Zyyy` Code for undetermined script (*Common*)
- `Zzzz` Code for uncoded script (*Unknown*)

The *Unicode Character Database* has a script property for each character.

For *PyICU*, we can use the `icu.Script` class. The `getScript()` method will create an internal script enumeration for a character. We can then use the `getName()` or `getShortName()` methods to get the name of script or the script code for the script.

*Unicodedataplus* provides the `unicodedataplus.script()` mehtod which returns the name of the script.

```py
import icu
import unicodedataplus as ud
num = "٣"
# To get name of script:
script_icu = icu.Script.getScript(num).getName()
print(script_icu)
# Arabic

# to get script code
script_code_icu = icu.Script.getScript(num).getShortName()
# 'Arab'

# Using Unicodedataplus:
script_ud = ud.script(num)
print(script_code_ud)
# Arabic
```

Likewise it is possible to get the *script extension* for a character. With *PyICU* we can use the `getScriptExtensions()` method, and with *Unicodedataplus* we can use the `unicodedataplus.script_extensions()` method:

```py
# gettng script extension names
script_ext_icu = [icu.Script(n).getName() for n in icu.Script.getScriptExtensions(num)]
print(script_ext_icu)
['Arabic', 'Thaana', 'Yezidi']

# getting script extension codes
script_ext_code_icu = [icu.Script(n).getShortName() for n in icu.Script.getScriptExtensions(num)]
print(script_ext_code_icu)
# ['Arab', 'Thaa', 'Yezi']

# Using Unicodedataplus
script_ext_ud = ud.script_extensions(num)
print(script_ext_ud)
# ['Arab', 'Thaa', 'Yezi']
```

We can use list comprehension, or other approaches to get a list of scripts in a string. A string, even in a single language, can contain more than one script:

```py
example = "Dɛ̈tëicëkäŋ akɔ̈ɔ̈n"
# Using PyICU
scripts_icu = set([icu.Script.getScript(char).getName() for char in example])
print(scripts)
# {'Inherited', 'Common', 'Latin'}
script_codes_icu = set([icu.Script.getScript(char).getShortName() for char in example])
# {'Zyyy', 'Zinh', 'Latn'}

# Using Unicodedataplus
scripts_ud = set([ud.script(char) for char in example])
print(scripts_ud)
# {'Inherited', 'Common', 'Latin'}
```

From the script and script extension properties it is possible to determine the dominant script for a string.