# Opening multiple files on Python Different Encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have kept a good number of files in a folder.
Now I want to read all of them. 
They are in different formats and different encoding.
Using `listdir/glob.glob` I am able to find the list but 
how to `open/read` or process them for different encodings?

If any one can help me out.I am using Python3.2 on Windows.

Regards,
Subhabrata Banerjee.

Comment: @Marcin: he did say that he tried using listdir.

Comment: @DavidRobinson And I can say that I wrote the world's most full-featured application. There's no reason not to show the code - it makes the question much more concrete. http://sscce.org/

Comment: How do you know what encoding each file is in?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know which files are in which encodings, use [codecs.open()](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/codecs.html?highlight=codec#codecs.open).  It works almost exactly like regular open(), but takes an optional encoding parameter.

If you don't know which files are in which encodings then it's more difficult.  You can try something like [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) or the other answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file)

Comment: and by 'more difficult' you mean 'impossible' in general case. `open()` on Python 3 supports `encoding` parameter

Answer (score 1):

`open(fp)` is the standard way of opening a file in python see: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open

once open you can read the the file by `.read()` as specified by http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects

The encodings are going to be more tricky, and will be based on how you know what encoding is used for each file

Answer (score 0):

As [Jeremiah wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11418564/1346705) (for ), `codecs.open()` does for Python 2 what modernized `open()` does for Python 3. The `encoding` argument says what encoding is used inside the file.

However, the **important difference** is that if `codecs.open()` is used, then read lines are unicode strings (and to be written lines are expected to be unicode strings), not the plain old strings (i.e. sequences of bytes). It is more natural feeling in Python 3, but it can also be done in Python 2 this way.

I do recommend to read Mark Pilgrim's *Dive Into Python 3*, [Chapter 4. Strings](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html).

His [Chapter 15. Case Study: Porting chardet to Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html) explains how the mentioned `chardet` module works.