# Encoding and Decoding of text in Python

Tags: python, string, urllib, url-encoding

I am currently working with a python script (appengine) that takes an input from the user (text) and stores it in the database for re-distribution later.

The text that comes in is *unknown*, in terms of encoding and I need to have it encoded only once.

Example Texts from clients:

- This%20is%20a%20test
- This is a test

Now in python what I thought I could do is decode it then encode it so both samples become:

- This%20is%20a%20test
- This%20is%20a%20test

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
#
# Dencode as UTF-8
#
pl = pl.encode('UTF-8')

#
#Unquote the string, then requote to assure encoding
#
pl = urllib.quote(urllib.unquote(pl))
```

Where `pl` is from the *POST* parameter for payload.

#### The Issue

The issue is that sometimes I get special (Chinese, Arabic) type chars and I get the following error.

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
    ..snip..
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xc3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

does anyone know the best solution to process the string given the above issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
pl = pl.encode('UTF-8')
```

with

```
pl = pl.decode('UTF-8')
```

since you're trying to decode a byte-string into a string of characters.

A design issue with Python 2 lets you `.encode` a bytestring (which is already encoded) by automatically decoding it as ASCII (which is why it apparently works for ASCII strings, failing only for non-ASCII bytes).