# Italian dected as iso-8859-2

Tags: python, encoding, chardet

I am using chardet to detect encoding of text files including Italian. The problem is it consistently detects their encoding as iso-8859-2 while the correct detection would be iso-8859-1. Does anybody know a fix? 
My local language is set to Polish? Could that influence the detection?

Comment: Since iso-8859-2 is for Eastern European languages, I would say that yes, that probably influences the detection. Which method do you use to detect the encoding?

Comment: Junuxx - I am using a 'detect' method e.g. chardet.detect(text)

Comment: I recommend reading the accepted answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chardet doesn't support iso-8859-1, that's why it's not detecting it.
For supported character encodings, see chardets homepage - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet.

I use the Linux program 'file' to get the character encoding of different content, however I'm not sure how safe it is, see my question - [Encoding detection in Python, use the chardet library or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591926/encoding-detection-in-python-use-the-chardet-library-or-not). But it works with great results for me so far.

Btw, your local language should not influence the detection.