# Python general unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I'm having problems understanding unicode in python 2.7.2, so I tried some tests in idle. Two things are marked 'not sure'.  Please tell me why they fail. As to the other items, please tell me if my comment is accurate.

```
>>> s
'Don\x92t '  # s is a string
>>> u
u'Don\u2019t '  # u is a unicode object
>>> type(u)     # confirm u is unicode
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type(s)     # confirm s is string
<type 'str'>
>>> type(s) == 'str' # wrong way to test
False
>>> isinstance(s, str)  # right way to test
True
>>> print s
Don’t       # works because idle can handle strings
>>> print u
Don’t       # works because idle can handle unicode
>>> open('9', 'w').write(s.encode('utf8')) #encode takes unicode, but s is a string,
                                            # so this fails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    open('9', 'w').write(s.encode('utf8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> open('9', 'w').write(s) # write can write strings
>>> open('9', 'w').write(u) # write can't write unicode

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
    open('9', 'w').write(u)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> open('9', 'w').write(u.encode('utf8'))  # encode turns unicode to string, which write can handle
>>> open('9', 'w').write(s.decode('utf8'))  # decode turns string to unicode, which write can't handle

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    open('9', 'w').write(s.decode('utf8'))
  File "C:\program files\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: invalid start byte
>>> e = '{}, {}'.format(s, u) # fails becase ''.format is string, while u is unicode

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    e = '{}, {}'.format(s, u)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> e = '{}, {}'.format(s, u.encode('utf8')) # works because u.encode is a string
>>> e = u'{}, {}'.format(s, u) # not sure

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    e = u'{}, {}'.format(s, u)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> e = u'{}, {}'.format(s.decode('utf8'), u) # not sure

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#55>", line 1, in <module>
    e = u'{}, {}'.format(s.decode('utf8'), u)
  File "C:\program files\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: invalid start byte

>>> e = '\n'.join([s, u]) # wants strings, but u is unicode

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 1, in <module>
    e = '\n'.join([s, u])
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> e = '\n'.join([s, u.encode('utf8')]) # u.encode is now a string
```

Comment: This is wrong: `>>> type(s) == 'str' # wrong way to test` `type()` is retuning a type, not a type in a string, so your test should be: `type(s) == str`, but you're right, it is better to use `isinstance()`

Comment: Please ask your question(s) in text, and use a question title that summarizes the question(s). Normally, you should ask separate questions separately.

Comment: If you have problems understanding Unicode in Python 2 and you do not really need python 2, then go ahead and stop trying to understand and install Python 3 instead. In Python 3 all this confusion is gone.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The concepts seem plain. It's implementation details, such as the u'{}'.format() matter. I'm dealing with music playlists and a playlist that works in one player may not work in another, which makes things harder. I was having problems with a tag reader, posted here and discovered it was a a bug rather than anything I was doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `s` is not a `utf-8` encoded string its probably `cp1250` encoded string. So decoding it using `utf-8` always fails.

```
>>> e = u'{}, {}'.format(s, u) # not sure
```

First "not sure" is because `u'{}, {}'` is `unicode` and tries to encode every argument of the `format` function to `unicode` string. But because it doesn't know what the `s` is encoded in, it assumes that `s` is encoded as `ascii`, so it tries to decode it as `ascii` (basically doing `s.decode('ascii')`) and fails since `s` is a `cp1250` encoded string.

```
>>> e = u'{}, {}'.format(s.decode('utf8'), u) # not sure
```

Second one fails because you tried to decode it as `utf-8` but it's actually, as said earlier, in some other encoding that is not compatible with `utf-8`.

Comment: The second one failed with: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 3: invalid start byte

Comment: Oh wait I missed it since I haven't tested the code. `s` is not a valid `utf-8` string. `s` is not encoded as `utf-8`. That is the problem. Valid `utf-8` version of `s` would be `'Don\xe2\x80\x99t '` So the decode fails.

Comment: Tested it, `s` is `cp1250` or `cp1251`. So you should use `decode('cp1250')`

Comment: Is there code to test which encoding to use?

Comment: Unfortunately no. :-/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file/436299#436299

Comment: There is also a [libguess](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-libguess) but it's a little bit out of date (not that encodings change much :D) but it may have some bugs...

Comment: Alas.  That link includes "An encoding discovered in the document itself" The document the string came from (an xml playlist from itunes) starts with "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" which led me to believe utf8 would work

Comment: How did you load the xml?

Comment: I loaded it with plistlib

Comment: Yes probably someone incorrectly encoded the file. Expat parser (plistlib uses it under the hood) should correctly decode values depending on the xml header.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 will *automatically* encode Unicode values, or decode string values when mixing string and unicode operations. This is where your confusion stems from.

When writing a Unicode value to a file, for example, Python 2 will try to encode that value to a string. Because no encoding has been specified, the *default* encoding is used instead, which on Python 2 is ASCII. The same goes for using a `str` value in a unicode context, Python 2 will decode it using the ASCII codec.

Your sample values, however, contain a codepoint or byte that is not representable as an ASCII character, so the automatic conversions fail. The `UnicodeEncodeError` or `UnicodeDecodeError` exceptions you see are the result of the automatic conversions.

Specifically, `e = u'{}, {}'.format(s, u)` tries to decode `s` to Unicode to interpolate it into the unicode `u'{}, {}'` template string.

To avoid automatic conversions, you thus need to use *explicit* conversions instead. And to use explicit conversions, you need to **know** the right encoding used for your byte string, or what codec you are targeting when encoding unicode.

Your computer is a *Windows* machine configured to use a Latin-1-like codepage, either the [1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) or [1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) codepage. That is why printing the `\x92` byte prints a `’` when you write that byte to the terminal directly.

Python knows your computer is configured with that codepage, if you print `sys.stdout.encoding` you'll see `cp1250` or `cp1252` or similar printed. That is why Python knows how to print a Unicode value and you'll see the `’` character when printing the `\u2019` codepoint.

Your `s` value is **not** encoded in UTF-8 however. Trying to decode that value *from* UTF8 will thus fail. You need to decode from `cp1252` instead:

```
>>> '\x92'.decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 0: invalid start byte
>>> '\x92'.decode('cp1252')
u'\u2019'
```

If you use `u'{}, {}'.format(s.decode('cp1252'), u)`, then no exception will be thrown as `s` can be decoded to Unicode correctly.

Comment: FWIW, the s value came from an itunes xml playlist starting with "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"  I suppose I should take it up with Apple :(

Comment: @foosion: are you certain? A proper XML parser gives you *unicode* values from such a file..

Comment: I'm certain the xml file was produced by itunes and that the header started with  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  I cut and paste s from the file into this question. I posted after reading the xml with plistlib and doing some processing failed unicode errors. I'll run some more tests.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275020/python-2-7-2-plistlib-with-itunes-xml/  It seems I may have found a bug in plistlib