# Python 2.7.2: plistlib with itunes xml

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, unicode, itunes

I'm reading an itunes generated xml playlist with plistib.  The xml has a utf8 header.

When I read the xml with plistib, I get both unicode (e.g., 'Name': u'Don\u2019t You Remember') and byte strings (e.g., 'Name': 'Where Eagles Dare').

Standard advice is to decode what you read with the correct encoding as soon as possible and use unicode within the program. However,

```
unicode_string.decode('utf8')
```

fails (as it should) with

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The solution would seem to be:

```
for name in names:
    if isinstance(name, str):
        name = name.decode('utf8')
    # etc.
```

Is this the correct way of dealing with the problem?  Is there a better way?

I'm on windows 7.

EDIT:

xml read with:

```
import plistlib
xml = plistlb.readPlist(fn)
for track in xml['Tracks']:
    info = xml['Tracks'][track]
    info['Name']
```

Produces in idle:

```
u'Don\u2019t You Remember'
'Where Eagles Dare'
```

Here's the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Major Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Minor Version</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Date</key><date>2013-08-14T15:04:27Z</date>
    <key>Application Version</key><string>10.6.3</string>
    <key>Features</key><integer>5</integer>
    <key>Show Content Ratings</key><true/>
    <key>Music Folder</key><string>file://localhost/C:/Users/rdp/Music/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/</string>
    <key>Library Persistent ID</key><string>FE28CCACD9A36C34</string>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1019</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>1019</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Where Eagles Dare</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Iron Maiden</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>Piece Of Mind</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Rock</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>7372755</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>370128</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Year</key><integer>1983</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2009-10-07T21:11:31Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2008-02-07T16:04:15Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>153</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Play Date</key><integer>3414416760</integer>
            <key>Play Date UTC</key><date>2012-03-12T21:06:00Z</date>
            <key>Artwork Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>FE28CCACD9A383E5</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/D:/music/Iron%20Maiden/Piece%20Of%20Mind/01%20Where%20Eagles%20Dare.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>11559</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>11559</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Don’t You Remember</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Adele</string>
            <key>Album</key><string>21</string>
            <key>Genre</key><string>Pop</string>
            <key>Kind</key><string>MPEG audio file</string>
            <key>Size</key><integer>6120028</integer>
            <key>Total Time</key><integer>229511</integer>
            <key>Track Number</key><integer>4</integer>
            <key>Track Count</key><integer>11</integer>
            <key>Year</key><integer>2011</integer>
            <key>Date Modified</key><date>2012-11-17T10:50:31Z</date>
            <key>Date Added</key><date>2012-12-19T16:03:46Z</date>
            <key>Bit Rate</key><integer>199</integer>
            <key>Sample Rate</key><integer>44100</integer>
            <key>Artwork Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Persistent ID</key><string>7130C888606FB153</string>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
            <key>Location</key><string>file://localhost/D:/music/Adele/21/04%20-%20Don%E2%80%99t%20You%20Remember.mp3</string>
            <key>File Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
            <key>Library Folder Count</key><integer>-1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>Playlists</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key><string>short</string>
            <key>Playlist ID</key><integer>30888</integer>
            <key>Playlist Persistent ID</key><string>166746C6572B0005</string>
            <key>All Items</key><true/>
            <key>Playlist Items</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>11559</integer>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>Track ID</key><integer>1019</integer>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: How does the plist file that causes this problem looks like, because this shouldn't happen. It should always return the same type.

Comment: I've included the xml file and the relevant python code.

Comment: Ick, indeed, `plistlib` in Python 2 is rather out of touch, old and archaic and will try to encode everything to ASCII. When that fails it leaves the data as Unicode. Bad, BAD module!

Comment: @MartijnPieters what would you recommend using to parse the itunes generated xml file?

Comment: ElementTree; parse the XML like any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this is a really weird behaviour. I would even say that this non-uniform behaviour is a bug in the 2.X implementation of the `plistlib`. The `plistlib` in Python 3 always returns unicode strings which is much better.

But you have to live with it :) So the answer to your question is yes. You should protect yourself always when reading a string from a `plist`

```
def safe_unicode(s):
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s
    return s.decode('utf-8', errors='replace')

value = safe_unicode(info['Name'])
```

I added the `errors='replace'` just in case the string is not `utf-8` encoded. You'll get a bunch of `\ufffd` characters if it cannot be decoded. If you rather get an exception just leave it out and use `e.decode('utf-8')`.

*Update:*

When I tried with ElementTree:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse('test.plist')
map(lambda x: x.text, tree.findall('dict/dict/dict')[1].findall('string'))
```

Which gave me:

```
[u'Don\u2019t You Remember',
 'Adele',
 '21',
 'Pop',
 'MPEG audio file',
 '7130C888606FB153',
 'File',
 'file://localhost/D:/music/Adele/21/04%20-%20Don%E2%80%99t%20You%20Remember.mp3']
```

So there are unicode and byte string mixed :-/

Comment: I would have thought plistlib had been around long enough to be clean of bugs.  Oh well.

Comment: Not a lot of people use it. As you can see in [hg log](http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/log/tip/Lib/plistlib.py) last time it was touched was 2011 :-/

Comment: Would you recommend ElementTree?

Comment: Just tested they both do the same thing :-/ They all use the same xml parser under the hood. Switching to python 3 would solve your problem though :)

Comment: For the moment, testing with isinstance (even my simple implementation) seems to work well enough, with everything I've thrown at it. Switching to Python 3, with its better treatment of unicode, is likely a good idea.

Comment: BTW, would you mind posting the code you used to test with ElementTree?