# unicode decode error: how to skip invalid characters

Tags: python

Is there any way to preprocess text files and skip these characters?

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa1 in position 1395: invalid start byte
```

Comment: can you show what you written???

Comment: Sure there is, but do you want to? Wouldn't it be better to use the proper codec for decoding in the first place so it all comes back intact?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/27329437/874188

Comment: @MarkRansom I guess the better question is then, how do you find the proper codec given a text file?

Comment: @MaximusS since you never told us where the data came from, we can't answer that question. Maybe you can?

Comment: what's the correct encoding for 0xc0? Nothing in python seems to be able to read this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.decode('utf-8',errors='ignore')
```

Comment: While this is the workaround the OP actually asks for, it is nearly always the wrong solution. The correct approach would be to identify the correct encoding, and decode that instead.

Comment: How do we read a file having invalid characters into str in the first place?

Comment: @nikhilvj   I know this is an old thread but for anyone else who landed here and realized that info is missing from the answer:   open the file in binary mode with the `'rb'` flag:   `content = open(filename, 'rb').read().decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')`

Comment: Additional information which would be good to have here is that the errors='ignore' can also be added to the open command so that if you are doing a with open you don't have to temporarily go to binary.

Answer (score 4):

I think your text file have some special character, so 'utf-8' can't decode.

You need to try using 'ISO-8859-1' instead of 'utf-8'. like this:

```
   import sys
   reload(sys).setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")

   # put your code here
```

Comment: There is no indication that this is the correct codec. All we can know is that the input is in a different encoding than UTF-8; the rest is guesswork.

Comment: Thank you! My file had a byte 0xc0 that was causing pandas to reject it. Hunted all around and this is the only place where an alternative encoding worked!