# Decode error with Pandas reading a .txt that only occurs on one compuer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, encoding

I have a comma-separated `.txt` file with French characters such as `Vétérinaire` and `Désinfectant`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('somefile.txt', sep=',', header=None, encoding='utf-8')

[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

I have read many Q&A posts (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276200/changing-default-encoding-of-python)) and tried many different encoding such as '`latin1`' and '`utf-16`', they didn't work. However, I tried to run the exact same script on the different Windows 10 computer with similar Python setup (all Python 3.6), it works perfectly fine in the other computer.

Edit: I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462807/encoding-error-in-panda-read-csv). Using `encoding='cp1252'` helps for some of the `.txt` files I want to import, but for a few `.txt` files, it gives the following error.

```
  File "C:\Program_Files_Extra\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 25: character maps to <undefined>
```

Edit:
Trying to identify encoding from chardet

```
import chardet 
import pandas as pd
test_txt = 'somefile.txt'

rawdata = open(test_txt, 'rb').read()
result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
charenc = result['encoding']

print (charenc)

df = pd.read_csv(test_txt, sep=',', header=None, encoding=charenc)

print (df.head())

utf-8
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

Comment: What OS do you have in the computer?

Comment: Both have windows 10 64-bits.

Comment: You could try to guess the encoding of the files by using chardet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269060/is-there-a-python-library-function-which-attempts-to-guess-the-character-encodin

Comment: Very strange, I used chardet and it identified the problematic .txt as `utf-8`.

Comment: Perhaps this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27456542/4001592, but indeed is very strange.

Comment: Thanks but I saw that before, seems like it's not a solution for Python 3 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127513/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-setdefaultencoding

Answer (score 0):

Your program opens your files with a default encoding and that doesn't match the contents of the file you are trying to open.

**Option 1:** Decode the file contents to python string objects:

```
rawdata = open(test_txt, 'rb', encoding='UTF8').read()
```

**Option 2:** Open the csv file in an editor like Sublime Text and save it with utf-8 encoding to easily read the file through pandas.