# Replace unicode characters only once in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to create a small script that replaces a set of characters in a file like this:

```
# coding=utf-8

import codecs
import os
import sys

args = sys.argv

if len(args) > 1:
    subtitleFileName = args[1]
    newSubtitleFileName = subtitleFileName + "_new"

    replacePairs = {
        u"ã": "ă",
        u"Ã": "Ă",
        u"º": "ș",
        u"ª": "Ș",
        u"þ": "ț",
        u"Þ": "Ț",
    }

    if os.path.isfile(subtitleFileName):
        oldSubtitleFile = codecs.open(subtitleFileName, "rb", "ISO-8859-1")

        subtitleContent = oldSubtitleFile.read()
        subtitleContent = codecs.encode(subtitleContent, "utf-8")

        for key, value in replacePairs.iteritems():
            subtitleContent = subtitleContent.replace(codecs.encode(key, "utf-8"), value)

        oldSubtitleFile.close()

        newSubtitleFile = open(newSubtitleFileName, "wb")
        newSubtitleFile.write(subtitleContent)
        newSubtitleFile.close()

        os.remove(subtitleFileName)
        os.rename(newSubtitleFileName, subtitleFileName)

        print "Done!"
    else:
        print "Missing subtitle file!"
else:
    print "Missing arguments!"
```

and it works ok for the first run.

So if I have a file containing `Eºti sigur cã vrei sã ºtergi fiºierele?`, after running the script on that file I get `Ești sigur că vrei să ștergi fișierele?` which is what I want. But if I run it multiple times I get:

> EÈti sigur cÄ vrei sÄ Ètergi fiÈierele?
>
> EĂÂti sigur cĂÂ vrei sĂÂ ĂÂtergi fiĂÂierele?
>
> EÄÂĂÂti sigur cÄÂĂÂ vrei sÄÂĂÂ ÄÂĂÂtergi fiÄÂĂÂierele?
>
> EĂÂĂÂÄÂĂÂti sigur cĂÂĂÂÄÂĂÂ vrei sĂÂĂÂÄÂĂÂ ĂÂĂÂÄÂĂÂtergi fiĂÂĂÂÄÂĂÂierele?

And I don't understand why. How does it find some characters that don't exist anymore in the file *(ã, º, etc.)* to be able to replace them? And why is it even replacing them with some other characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple - it's because on the first run you're reading ISO-8859-1 and writing UTF-8. Then on the second run you're doing exactly the same despite the input is now UTF-8 not ISO-8859-1. On subsequent runs the search and replace is no longer working.

This test mimics your 2nd iteration - Interpreting UTF-8 as ISO-8859-1  :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "Ești sigur că vrei să ștergi fișierele?".decode("ISO-8859-1")
>> EÈti sigur cÄ vrei sÄ Ètergi fiÈierele?
```

The next iteration looks like:

```
print "Ești sigur că vrei să ștergi fișierele?".decode("ISO-8859-1").encode("utf-8").decode("ISO-8859-1")
>> EÃÂti sigur cÃÂ vrei sÃÂ ÃÂtergi fiÃÂierele?
```

Heed @Daniel's advice to decode once, replace Unicode with Unicode then encode once. I've also been informed that it's best to use `io.open()` rather than `codecs`, as its Python 3 compatible and solves a problem with universal new lines.

Comment: And is it possible to check a file's encoding? So if it's not `ISO-8859-1`, it skips the replacing.

Comment: Accurately detecting character encoding is very difficult. If you know what the text is supposed to say you could compare the input to a string in the correct encoding. Alternativly, there's some good Python libs which try to guess the encoding and may be sufficient for what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file

Comment: @Iulian, write out the "byte object mark" at the beginning of your output file. It's not required or recommended for utf-encoded files, but it is invisible to text editors and it's a standard way to identify unicode. Better yet: Change your workflow so you know how your files are encoded without having to check.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack, I think that the easiest solution would be to leave the original file intact, so if I mistakenly run my script on `subtitle.srt` it would produce `subtitle_fixed.srt` every time, replacing _(with no gain, nor harm)_ the old one.

Comment: Google "Unicode BOM". Windows editors add it to the start of unicode files, so you're safe adding it too.

Comment: @alexis It's a novel idea (I upvoted you) but it's not entirely safe, especially when dealing with .srt for closed platforms - not all devices understand Byte **Order** Marks.

Comment: @Alastair I agree (I even said it's not recommended), but since he's on Windows it's a pretty safe bet. Still, it's far better to adopt a saner filename scheme...

Comment: @alexis, So something like my comment about `subtitle_fixed.srt`?

Comment: I've just looked at the .srt Wikipedia page. It looks like the safe thing to do (when dealing with Western languages) is to encode to `windows-1252` rather than utf-8: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#Text_encoding

Comment: Just noticed I somehow typed "object" instead of "order" mark. Embarassing... Thanks for catching it, @Alastair!

Comment: I won't bother to guess what the wikipedia entry is trying to say, but CP-1252 is an 8-bit encoding. Only the ASCII part (i.e., the low page) is "compatible" with UTF-8. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't work with encoded content. Only encode when writing the new file:

```
import codecs
import os
import sys

args = sys.argv

if len(args) > 1:
    subtitleFileName = args[1]
    newSubtitleFileName = subtitleFileName + "_new"

    replacePairs = {
        u"ã": u"ă",
        u"Ã": u"Ă",
        u"º": u"ș",
        u"ª": u"Ș",
        u"þ": u"ț",
        u"Þ": u"Ț",
    }

    if os.path.isfile(subtitleFileName):
        with codecs.open(subtitleFileName, "rb", "ISO-8859-1") as oldSubtitleFile:
            subtitleContent = oldSubtitleFile.read()

        for key, value in replacePairs.iteritems():
            subtitleContent = subtitleContent.replace(key, value)

        with codecs.open(newSubtitleFileName, "wb", "utf-8") as newSubtitleFile:
            newSubtitleFile.write(subtitleContent)

        os.remove(subtitleFileName)
        os.rename(newSubtitleFileName, subtitleFileName)

        print "Done!"
    else:
        print "Missing subtitle file!"
else:
    print "Missing arguments!"
```

Comment: Still keeps replacing like before.

Answer (score 0):

It is incorrect to use `"ISO-8859-1"` character encoding on `"utf-8"` content: the very first time you run your script it takes a text file (presumably `"ISO-8859-1"` encoded) and saves it as `"utf-8"` while replacing certain Unicode characters.

Then you run the conversion the second time then it takes `"utf-8"` content and tries to interpret it as `"ISO-8859-1"` that is *wrong*.

To avoid the confusion make the replacements separately from the changing of the character encoding. Thus the replacements would be idempotent.

To make the replacements, you could use `fileinput` module and `unicode.translate()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Replace some characters in 'iso-8859-1'-encoded files."""
import fileinput # read files given on the command-line and/or stdin

replacements = {
    u"ã": u"ă",
    u"Ã": u"Ă",
    u"º": u"ș",
    u"ª": u"Ș",
    u"þ": u"ț",
    u"Þ": u"Ț",
}
# key => ord(key)
replacements = dict(zip(map(ord, replacements.keys()), replacements.values()))
for line in fileinput.input(openhook=fileinput.hook_encoded("iso-8859-1")):
    print(line.translate(replacements))
```

To control the encoding of the output file, you could set `PYTHONIOENCODING` e.g., in bash:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python replace-chars.py iso-8859-1.txt >replaced.utf-8
```

This command both replaces the characters and transcodes the input from `"iso-8859-1"` to `"utf-8"`.

If input `filename.txt` is already broken (no single character encoding correctly decodes it) then you could [try `ftfy` module](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy) to fix common encoding errors:

```
$ ftfy filename.txt >filename.utf8.txt
```

Comment: Using this code snippet I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0219' in position 4: character maps to <undefined>` in console _(running on Windows)_.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei set PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable (using cmd.exe -specific syntax) and *redirect* output to a file as shown in the answer (using `>` opetator).