# Accent Mac encoding

Tags: python, macos, csv, pandas, encoding

I have a CSV file with various accented entries and other symbols. When I open it with Mac's TextEdit, they show nicely, but when I open it with Excel or on Python using pandas, the different characters get all messed up.

As an example, `4º Centenário` becomes `4¼ Centenrio`.

What's the encoding I should use (on pandas specifically) to read these special characters properly?

Comment: whichever encoding you want, just make sure it's the **SAME** encoding on both sides.

Comment: Right but I want to know what the encoding actually _is_, because I need to be able to read those characters from the file and I don't seem to be able to.

Comment: start with the basics: assume utf8

Comment: I've assumed utf8, various parts of iso-8859, and cp860 (the document is in Portuguese) to no avail.

Comment: win-1252? it's extremely hard to reliably detect char encodings, because any given file could be completely valid in multiple charsets, yet have totally different renderings.

Comment: It's really just a regular mac os file, using the mac ways of accenting things (e.g. option+e then vowel for an acute accent).

Comment: Have you tried chardet? It's a python module that tries to detect encoding. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet

Comment: relevant? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/146874?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Is there a way to determine the encoding of text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file)