# Python 2.7 check if a file is encoded with UTF-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8

My current solution is just read all bytes of a file, try to decode, if any exception, I will say this file is not properly encoded. Any other more elegant ways? Thanks.

```
utfbytes.decode('utf-8')
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Is there a way to determine the encoding of text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file)

Comment: Thanks @DeanFenster, vote up. If I do not use the 3rd party library, my current solution of leveraging Python 2.7 built-in solution is already good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436299/2483271)**. From that answer:

> Correctly detecting the encoding all times is impossible.
>
> (From chardet FAQ:)
>
> > However, some encodings are optimized for specific languages, and languages are not random. Some character sequences pop up all the time, while other sequences make no sense. A person fluent in English who opens a newspaper and finds “txzqJv 2!dasd0a QqdKjvz” will instantly recognize that that isn't English (even though it is composed entirely of English letters). By studying lots of “typical” text, a computer algorithm can simulate this kind of fluency and make an educated guess about a text's language.

However, there are [some libraries](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit) that exist that do make the best effort to try and find the encoding type.

Comment: Thanks Nick, vote up. If I do not use the 3rd party library, my current solution of leveraging Python 2.7 built-in solution is already good?

Comment: Your solution looks perfect, as long as you handle exceptions!

Comment: Sure, thanks Nick. Have a good weekend. Vote up and mark your reply as answer.

Comment: @LinMa Thanks happy to help, and to yourself!