# How to decode a mail in Python whatever the encoding?

Tags: python, email, module, package, decoding

I'm working on a NLP project for classifying email in Python. The main goal is to build a model that automatically redirect mails to the good service. I try to build a database with only the customers text mail and their demand.
I started to load the emails on the pop server with poplib and it works good.

I'm looking for a solution to decode any mail whatever the encoding.
I'm really not expert with encodings and I use a code that doesn't always work, I can't figure out why ..
I remark that it doesn't work on old messages, probably they are archived in one more different encoding.
I need a method that can detect and decode systematically, I searched on the web for two days and found nothing! Only website which propose to do it but I would like to integrate it directly in my code. I only need the body of the mail.

Does such a package exist? And if yes, which ?

Thanks a lot for reading me

Comment: iirc there is a few packages that try to do this(chardet I think is the one i used)  ... they get it wrong sometimes if i recall my pain with this ...

Comment: You may have a look at [Python - Auto Detect Email Content Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235436/python-auto-detect-email-content-encoding)