# Decoding bytes to string in python

Tags: python, byte

i've got a row of bytes: `'\udcd0\udca0\udcd0\udcbe\udcd1\udc81\udcd0\udcbd\udcd0\udcb5\udcd1\udc84\udcd1\udc82\udcd1\udc8c'`

If i do:

```
b'\udcd0\udca0\udcd0\udcbe\udcd1'.decode("utf8"),
```

I recieve:

```
'\\udcd0\\udca0\\udcd0\\udcbe\\udcd1'
```

I cant decode it, because i dont know, how it was encoded. At least, we can see, that its not `utf-8`, because, symbols i expect to see, have a `\x23`-similar representation. How can i discover the decoder and decode it?

**P.S.** i expect to see russian symbols there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file

Comment: @Jakub Thank you very much, but for some reason, i cant install any of suggested libraries. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to print your string in this way, but the output is all "invalid characters."

```
>>> string = u'\udcd0\udca0\udcd0\udcbe\udcd1\udc81\udcd0\udcbd\udcd0\udcb5\udcd1\udc84\udcd1\udc82\udcd1\udc8c'
>>> print string
����������������
```

According to [Charbase.com](http://www.charbase.com/dcd0-unicode-invalid-character), your first character (u'\udcd0') is invalid character. So maybe the output is correct.