# Finding out the correct encoding, given the decoded string for a certain format

Tags: python, encoding

In Python, I opened a file using the `iso-8859-1` encoding. This file is huge, and I'm trying to find the right encoding. I know that it decoded the word fröhliche as frÃ¶hliche. Knowing this, is there a way to find the right encoding? I've tried utf-8 and it's unable to decode the file.

Comment: What do you mean by the "right encoding"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine the encoding of text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/determine-the-encoding-of-text-in-python)