# beautifulsoup webscraping problems

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse youtube with beautifulsoup, but without luck.
I've parsed many websites which all went perfect, but this ones doesn't work and gives me this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2117' in position 135588: character maps to <undefined>
```

I decoded it as following:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")


x = page_soup.find('div',{'id':"dismissable"})
```

I still get the error above. 
but when i try this:

Code:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser").encode("utf-8")
```

with encoding it i'm able to print out my webpage, but when i search in it as following:

```
search_list = page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':"style-scope ytd-video-renderer"})

print(len(search_list))
```

I get the following Error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Any advice would be welcome.

much thanks.

additionally my code:

```
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen

import requests

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
set_Link = set([''])

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=the+lumineers+sleep+on+the+floor'

r = http.request('get',url)

page_html = r.data #html data opslaan in variabele

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser").encode("utf-8")


print(page_soup)

search_list = page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':"style-scope ytd-video-renderer"})

print(len(search_list))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code applies `decode()` in the wrong place, hence the exception:

```
page_soup = soup(page_html.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

i did exactly what you said but still got the same error: 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2117' in position 149996: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: That means that the page is not in `utf-8` (probably some legacy MS Windows encoding?). Look at this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220) about detecting encoding.

Comment: I digged a bit deaper in it, but as it seems for me, the data i want to collect isn't available, because there's javascript behind it =/  I'll have to use the youtube API

Answer (score 0):

Just some advice for the first half of your question - you should use the 'unicode sandwich' approach and save yourself a lot of frustration:

1. Make your input unicode (BeautifulSoup does this for you)
2. Process in unicode

   - if you want to `print()` something, use `print(repr(string))`
3. Encode your output as required

Your first problem, the UnicodeEncodeError - was that the result of using a print statement on a string? If so, print like this:

```
print(repr(string))
```

to avoid encoding issues and keep your data in unicode until the end.

I.e. don't do this: `page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser").encode("utf-8")` just to print out the result.

Comment: Thank you sir! I have to admit, i had no knowledge about the "unicode sandwich" greate advice!