# Best way to detect (utf) encoding in unknown file

Tags: python, csv, unicode, byte-order-mark

Here is what I'm currently using to open a various file that the user has:

```
# check the encoding quickly
with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
    start_data = fp.read(4)
    if start_data.startswith(b'\x00\x00\xfe\xff'):
        encoding = 'utf-32'
    elif start_data.startswith(b'\xff\xfe\x00\x00'):
        encoding = 'utf-32'
    elif start_data.startswith(b'\xfe\xff'):
        encoding = 'utf-16'
    elif start_data.startswith(b'\xff\xfe'):
        encoding = 'utf-16'
    else:
        encoding = 'utf-8'            

# open the file with that encoding
with open(file, 'r', encoding=encoding) as fp:
    do_something()
```

Would there be a better way than the above to properly open an unknown utf file?

Answer (score 0):

If you know it is `utf`, you could use `chardet` to do something like:

```
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector

detector = UniversalDetector()

with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
    detector.feed(fp.read(1000))
    detector.close()
    raw = detector.result['encoding'].lower()
    encoding = 'utf-32' if ('utf-32' in raw) else 'utf-16' if ('utf-16' in raw) else 'utf-8'
```

Note: trying `magic` or some of the other libraries mentioned in the question here [Determine the encoding of text in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/436220/10332687) did not work. Additionally, note that a lot of times the file is in `utf-8` it will be marked as `ascii`.