# How to decode from an unknown encoding in PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

My question is different from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through). I am trying to fix a broken encoding but I don't know how to proceed.

In my database I have this name:

```
mysql> select filename from file WHERE filename LIKE 'MAC%';
+-------------------------------------------------+
| filename                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| MAC-1600PVå–æ‰±èª¬æ˜Žæ›¸.pdf                   |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But on my filesystem the file is named:

```
$ ls files/*MAC*
files/MAC-1600PV取扱説明書.pdf
```

I have tried to unpack both strings from PHP and the content differ:

The utf-8 sequence read from the filesystem:

```
=> "MAC-1600PV取扱説明書"
>>> unpack('C*', $u)
...
7 => 48,
8 => 48,
9 => 80,
10 => 86,
11 => 195,
12 => 165,
13 => 226,
14 => 128,
15 => 147,
16 => 195,
17 => 166,
18 => 226,
```

And for the one read from the database:

```
...
7 => 48,
8 => 48,
9 => 80,
10 => 86,
11 => 229,
12 => 143,
13 => 150,
14 => 230,
15 => 137,
16 => 177,
```

So at some-point I lost the original encoding and I have no clue of how to fix my database which is in `utf8mb4`.

Any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: How was the file name written? How is your DB connection set up? Maybe you can scan your directory and rewrite all the DB references?

Comment: Are your columns set to `utf8mb4`? Is your DB connection set to `utf8mb4`?

Comment: I am suspecting the initial "insert" that was wrong I don't think my database is faulty

Comment: @Dharman, yes the collation for both the table and the columns are `utf8mb4`, but I think the bug was made before inserting to the database, perhaps 10 years ago. I have few files like this and I don't know how to fix the broken encoding.

Comment: `utf8mb4` wasn't around in 2009 so likely it was another charset then.

Comment: You may look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/determine-the-encoding-of-text-in-python (python) but PHP has libmagic, and probably someone ported chardet in PHP, or you can look the code and inspire from it for your detection).