# Junk character while reading email body in python using win32com.client

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation, com-automation

I am trying to read email body As bellow but getting junk characters

```
for account in EmailsAccounts:
    print(account)
    inbox = outlook.Folders(account).Folders('Inbox')
    messages=inbox.Items
    print(len(messages))
    for mail in messages:
        body = mail.Body
        print(body.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Do you get the same results with HTMLBody instead of Body?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, when i tried with HTMLBody. i am getting HTMLBody not defined error

Comment: Have you tries checking the item type? Is it a mail item?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev, yes item is mail type

Comment: when i read subject , i am able to get as text but only body of the mail is coming as junk

Comment: Do you get the same problem with VBA macros?

Comment: you could show what characteds you get, and what charactes you expected.

Comment: `encode()` is converting `string` to `bytes` and it may looks different than you expect. Maybe you shouldn't use `encode()`. Other common problem is that mails send text in different encoding then `utf-8` - ie in `latin1`.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is related to encoding message bodies, try to use the following code instead:

```
print (mail.Body.encode('utf8'))
```

See [Is there a way to get around unicode issues when using win32api/com modules in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54299203/is-there-a-way-to-get-around-unicode-issues-when-using-win32api-com-modules-in-p) for more information.

If it is another problem I'd suggest check the message type - an Outlook folder may contain different kind of items such as appointments, tasks, documents or mail items.

Comment: using above solution i am getting hex character as bellow b'\xe6\xa0\ , is there way to convert in text formate

Comment: It makes sense to check out how it works with VBA macros. Do you get the same picture?

Comment: bellow thread is solving in VBA same solution i am looking python    https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/problem-in-vba-reading-text-from-body-of-out-of/1d8ca369-a4c0-41da-9d28-3f490de3ed8c