# different python between utf-8 and utf-8 BOM?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have the task to check the encoding of a file. Actually, my problem is the encoding formats which python provides in its `encoding` function. I´m very new to python so I think that I overlook something.

I can´t understand the following points:

- When I´m encoding a file which has the `utf-8` BOM format then the encoding function tells me that it is `utf-8`.
- When I´m checking the iso8859_6 format then it tells me that he couldn´t recognize this format even though the file has the iso8859_6 format but in case I check "cp720" then it´s able to recognize it

According to this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html), it should be able to recognize the `iso8859_6` format

I´ve tried to find something understandable in the www but couldn´t find something.

```
import codecs
import io

class Format:

    def __init__(self, file_Name):
        self.file_Name = file_Name

    def check_coding(self):

        encoding_formats = ['iso8859_6','utf-8', 'utf-8-sig', 'ascii']


        for ex in encoding_formats:
            try: 
                fh = codecs.open(self.file_Name, 'r', encoding=ex)

                fh.readlines()
                fh.close()

            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                    print('Die angelieferte Datei ist nicht nach %s  kodiert' % ex)
                    response = False;
            else:
                print('Angelieferte Datei besitzt folgende Kodierung:  %s ' % ex)
                response = True;
                break

        return response
```

`file_Name` format is `utf-8` BOM so it shouldn´t tell me it´s `utf-8`.

if the `file_Names` format is `iso8859_6` it tells me that it´s not coded in this format even though it is.

Comment: Are you able to share a minimal string which, when encoded and written to file, reproduces these behaviours?  Also, note that UTF-8 will always decode ASCII successfully, so if you want to detect ASCII you'll need to put it before UTF-8 in the encodings list.

Comment: There's no guarantee that using the wrong codec will cause an exception. And snakecharmerb's note about ASCII also applies to UTF-8-sig.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes the input of the file is this text: Diese Datei ist eine Testdatei für das Python Encoding Modul

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks for your note

Comment: If you accept text files that use a character encoding from a limited list, you should only need to check that each file is valid for the one encoding that it uses.  If you don't know what that is, you have a process problem that is resulting in data loss.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the encoding of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text)

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks for your information. But could you explain what you exactly mean with data loss or the process problem?

Comment: There is no text but encoded text. When you receive the bytes for text, they are meaningless without knowledge of the character encoding. There are various ways this might be communicated. If the bytes are received through an HTTP GET response body, the response's [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) should say. If the bytes are received through an HTTP POST with an HTML file upload, a different field should have asked the user to supply the character encoding or MIME type (or just tell them to only supply UTF-8 files, for example).