# How to find out the correct encoding when using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, python-requests

In python3 and beautifulsoup4 I want to get information from a website, after making the requests. I did so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('https://sisgvarmazenamento.blob.core.windows.net/prd/PublicacaoPortal/Arquivos/201901.htm').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(req,'lxml')

soup.find("h1").text
'\r\n                        CÃ\x82MARA MUNICIPAL DE SÃ\x83O PAULO'
```

I do not know what the encoding is, but it's a site with Brazilian Portuguese, so it should be utf-8 or latin1

Please, is there a way to find out which encoding is correct?

And then do the beautifulsoup read this encoding correctly?

Comment: Look at : [How to determine the encoding of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests determines encoding like [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/e73a6c52d205915c4d84e24ba01a5cd67e37d094/docs/user/advanced.rst#encodings):

> When you receive a response, Requests makes a guess at the encoding to use for decoding the response when you access the `Response.text` attribute. Requests will first check for an encoding in the HTTP header, and if none is present, will use chardet to attempt to guess the encoding.
>
> The only time Requests will not do this is if no explicit charset is present in the HTTP headers and the Content-Type header contains text. In this situation, RFC 2616 specifies that the default charset must be ISO-8859-1. Requests follows the specification in this case. If you require a different encoding, you can manually set the `Response.encoding` property, or use the raw `Response.content`.

Inspecting the request headers show that indeed "no explicit charset is present in the HTTP headers and the Content-Type header contains text"

```
>>> req.headers['content-type']
'text/html'
```

So requests faithfully follows the standard and decodes as ISO-8859-1 (latin-1).

In the response content, a charset is specified:

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-16">
```

however this is wrong: decoding as UTF-16 produces mojibake.

`chardet` correctly identifies the encoding as UTF-8.

So to summarise:

- there is no general way to determine text encoding with complete accuracy
- in this particular case, the correct encoding is UTF-8.

Working code:

```
>>> req.encoding = 'UTF-8'
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text,'lxml')
>>> soup.find('h1').text
'\r\n                        CÂMARA MUNICIPAL DE SÃO PAULO'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use requests, you can use the **encoding** function, for example:

```
req = requests.get('https://sisgvarmazenamento.blob.core.windows.net/prd/PublicacaoPortal/Arquivos/201901.htm')

encoding = req.encoding
text = req.content

decoded_text = text.decode(encoding)
```

Comment: Thank you @simonjansson. Now I am searching how to correctly read the encoding ISO-8859-1

Comment: Thank you very much @simonjansson, but I still continue to make mistakes. After the above commands, I did: soup = BeautifulSoup(decoded_text, "lxml")

Comment: It's the result: soup.find("h1") -> <h1>
                        CÃMARA MUNICIPAL DE SÃO PAULO<br/></h1>

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, can it be that?

Comment: One moment, I noticed now that the text on my screen appears wrong, but when I copied it it was correct ...

Comment: Yeah i think it depends on which language you have on your Ubuntu :)

Comment: Use: soup.find('h1')     -    Not: soup.find('h1').text

Comment: Thank you @simonjansson, but the error persists: CÃMARA MUNICIPAL DE SÃO PAULO

Comment: And when the saved the result as CSV also