# Issue with parsing special characters in a utf-8 encoded page with bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, character-encoding

I’m trying to parse a page and I’m having some issue with special characters such as é è à, etc.

According to the Firefox page information tool, the page is encoded in UTF - 8

My code is the following :

```py
import bs4
import requests


url = 'https://www.registreentreprises.gouv.qc.ca/RQEntrepriseGRExt/GR/GR99/GR99A2_05A_PIU_AfficherMessages_PC/ActiEcon.html'

page = requests.get(url)

cae_obj_soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
list_all_domain = cae_obj_soup.find_all('th')

for element in list_all_domain:
    print(element.get_text())
```

The output is :

```
PÃªche et piÃ©geage
Exploitation forestiÃ¨re
```

I tried changing the encoding with `iso-8859-1` (French encoding) and some other encodings without success. I read several posts on parsing special characters, and they basically states that it’s an issue of selecting the right encoding. Is there a possibility that I can’t decode correctly the special characters on some specific webpage or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests library takes [a strict approach to the decoding of web pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56404834/5320906).  On the other hand, BeautifulSoup has powerful tools for determining the encoding of text.  So it's better to pass the raw response from the request to BeautifulSoup, and [let BeautifulSoup try to determine the encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55872912/5320906).

```py
>>> r = requests.get('https://www.registreentreprises.gouv.qc.ca/RQEntrepriseGRExt/GR/GR99/GR99A2_05A_PIU_AfficherMessages_PC/ActiEcon.html')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
>>> list_all_domain = soup.find_all('th')
>>> [e.get_text() for e in list_all_domain]
['Agriculture', "Services relatifs à l'agriculture", 'Pêche et piégeage', ...]
```