# Trying to nail down the file encoding of a log file using UnicodeDammit?

Tags: python-3.x, file-encodings, unicode-dammit

Though I understand that it is sometimes impossible to determine a file encoding, I'm trying here.

## Bash

In bash `file` yields:
`Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators`

## vim

In Vim the `ex` command `:set fileencoding=?` yields:
 
`fileencoding=latin1`

If I open the file normally (see above) I get an `<92>` (hex 92); but if open the file with `:e ++enc=cp1252` I get `’`.

I looked up the `’` in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and it's part of code page 1252 a and that page also states that that code page is in the `80-9F` range, so I turned on `hlsearch` to highlight the matches...and when I do the following searches:

`/[^\x80-\x9F]` appears to match all characters (I could be wrong about that) since `/[\x80-\x9F]` matches none!

So this file isn't encoded in `cp1252` since all of it's characters fall outside of that range.

## Python using `chardet` and Unicode, Dammit!

`chardet` yields [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)

```
{'encoding': 'Windows-1252', 'confidence': 0.73, 'language': ''}
```

And I tried to use [bs4's dependency UnicodeDammit](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) to figure it out but it just returns `None`

```
# `cwd`: current directory is straightforward
cwd = Path.cwd()
relPath = '../attempt1_no_extra_fields/again/logfile.txt'
mod_path = Path('__file__').parent
file_path = (mod_path / relPath ).resolve()

with open(file_path, 'rb') as dfe:
    detection = chardet.detect(dfe.read())

print('Chardet:', detection)

with open(file_path, encoding=detection['encoding']) as non_unicode_file:
    data = non_unicode_file.read()

dammit = UnicodeDammit(data,["iso-8859-1","latin-1"])


print("dammit.original_encoding:", dammit.original_encoding)
```

gives:

```
`dammit.original_encoding: None`
```

I turned to `Unicode Dammit` because it has been said it will give you a [better determination of the file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436299/18149).