# how to check string if it's ascii-base and which one?

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, ascii, non-ascii-characters

How can I know if a string is ascii format and whiche base like: base64,or base32 ...
with python
I tried

```
import base64
from binascii import Error
try:
        string = base64.b64decode(data)
except Error:
        return False
```

the problem with this code that's it isn't accurate and doesn't tell which base is the string

Comment: It's not even valid syntactically. What are you trying to do here? Could you give some inputs and expected vs actual outputs?

Comment: you mean like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text)?

Comment: the input is a string and output is whether the string is encoded in binascii and which base Hope i explained thank you :)