# How to handle the network message with unicode that is not decodeable to utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I receive the following byte message via  socket connection and  I want to convert into string and do further processing I am using python3.7

below is the code i tried so far

```
import  codecs

a = b'0400F224648188E0801200000040000000001941678904000010237890000000000000222220418151856038556051259950760020806002468060046010403319     HSBCBSB8001101234567890MC   100  WITH ORDERIN   FO           AU009006Q\x00\x00\x00\x83\x00007\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x02010003855604181518562468000000000460100000'

b= codecs.decode(a, 'utf-8')

print(b)
```

Iam getting the error as below

```
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position    > 208: invalid start byte
```

how can I convert the data to string and process further

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code ran successfully for me with encoding='latin1'. Try `b= codecs.decode(a, 'latin1')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not utf-8 encoded. You can use BeautifulSoup to decode unknown encodings:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(b'0400F224648188E0801200000040000000001941678904000010237890000000000000222220418151856038556051259950760020806002468060046010403319     HSBCBSB8001101234567890MC   100  WITH ORDERIN   FO           AU009006Q\x00\x00\x00\x83\x00007\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00%\x02010003855604181518562468000000000460100000'
)
print(soup.contents[0])

print(soup.originalEncoding)
```

to get

```
0400F224648188E0801200000040000 ... # etc
```

and

```
windows-1252
```

---

You can use the bs4-detector seperately as well:    [UnicodeDammit](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) and also provide it with suggestions which encodings to try first / not to try to finetune it.

More info on SO:

- [How to determine the encoding of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text)

Comment: Wow, I was unaware that `BeautifulSoup` can be used to find the encoding format of a byte object.

Comment: @Cav You can even use the special part that does it seperately - see docu link I edited into answer