# CSV encoding , Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i  am trying to get rid off  strings like \xa0 \xc2 etc.. I know that is an encoding problem but how i'll do this ? 
Non of **utf-8** , **"ISO-8859-1"** encoding option worked for me..

```
train = pd.read_csv('./data/train.csv',index_col = False,low_memory = False,encoding='utf-8')

test = pd.read_csv('./data/test.csv',index_col = False,low_memory = False,encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

This is the output after using

```
train = pd.DataFrame(data = train)
print(train)
```

```
        Insult  Date    Comment

1   0   20120528192215Z "i really don't understand your point.\xa0 It ...
2   0   NaN "A\\xc2\\xa0majority of Canadians can and has ...
3   0   NaN "listen if you dont wanna get married to a man...
4   0   20120619094753Z "C\xe1c b\u1ea1n xu\u1ed1ng \u0111\u01b0\u1edd...
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/436299/5386938

Answer (score 0):

You can try regex like this :

```
string_cleaned = "string_contatining_unicode_or_latin".replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
```

For more info : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Another best way most recommended : [unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize)

Hope it helps