# After reading a big CSV file from pandas I am getting an absurd output of the file in my workbook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, encoding

> I am reading a very Big CSV file from pandas in return when I am checking the output of the file it is throwing some absurd result:

```
projects=pd.read_csv('Projects.csv', sep='delimiter', header=None,engine='python',encoding='latin-1',skiprows=2)
```

I have tried many conditions by changing the encoding method and many of the other conditions still, I am receiving the same output

```
    0
0   æ®&ý%|ÈÍêc7*Àòç¯NãÃ§&ûãßöû3ü·oäAÏ6Å6o£¤...
1   aTÝ¤ã[ÓÓ:Î»q8ÝïJÃ§ÝpG­Ô¨ñað¢@·-,éD¿¨...
2   nªz¤/Âz?ã·Á|ø0v³¾R?3 CÓë_æàßv...
3   GPÃóNÝHÝèÆ¡Gár#Ý
4   GÍÅ9âÂQ²?8;)MÏ`5ÀôÚL3íºãÒÖõð­aßãÂÔ...
5   <ÈÞ-Ü¹Þ½¥Æ£¯»àÏÝ}·ÇÒÃpo»ã¾ë5ÝBù{}~þô...
6   _wü-H|gw¦wò4ÉùÃ5nnÔÃo°ºnn`½³÷¶^...
7   ù4iZÓYU{=ó'Í¥çÂ¾·xüé¢ÁüURnÂÕ«Ý=nû®...
8   gT:5Ý¾,ãC7àzÞÃ)E;îîÙ³'$üÃAÀ
9   F:i¸Í-IÅX¾ÒÃxß)éx{ï`0%¬ì2û70aàÖ±...
10  ^o+=7|5ÊØ`ø~@ýLÀÛ5YSvú÷t<gcxÃpåv»ûÇï...
```

It would be great help If I get it resolved!

Comment: Probably have the wrong encoding.

Comment: use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167602/9375102) to detect your encoding then pass that in ass an argument

Comment: @Datanovice the encoding is ANSI I have tried this as an argument, still doesn't  solve the issue

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a binary file with a .csv extension? (doen't look like xls or xlsx but maybe some other type?). Sure you tried UTF-16 LE and BE? --- Oh, I see you skipped the first 2 rows.. so it could be xls or xlsx maybe.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a binary file (`.xls` or `.xlsx`) with a `.csv` extension.

There's only one 'field' in each row, so no delimiter is found.

Since you skipped the first 2 rows, I can't check the file signature to be sure.

---

Looking at the histogram of the small data sample you provided, it looks like this is compressed data and probably a `.xlsx` file (which is actually a zip file).