# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 341: invalid start byte

Tags: python, numpy

I try to load data, but I get this error message:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 341: invalid start byte

Does anyone know what I can do?
numpy version: '1.19.2'

Code:

```
>>> raw_data_np = np.genfromtxt("loan-data.csv", delimiter = ';', skip_header = 1, autostrip = True)

>>> raw_data_np
```

Comment: You are reading a textual file, assuming that it is saved as utf-8, but it is not a valid utf-8 file. You should find out in which encoding it was saved and use the `encoding` argument of `genfromtxt` to specify the correct encoding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```py
raw_data_np = np.genfromtxt('loan-data.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=1, autostrip=True,
                            encoding='cp855')
```

or

```py
raw_data_np = np.genfromtxt('loan-data.csv', delimiter=';', skip_header=1, autostrip=True,
                            encoding='ANSI')
```