# Characters mess up during encoding of European Characters

Tags: python, encoding, file-io, character-encoding

I am currently trying to output a csv file with a few European languages like German and Spanish. When I create the file, I need to specify an encoding in order to not get messed up output. I tried iso-8859 and cp1252, but there has to be at least a few characters that are messed up (meaning that they are not from the language).
Code:

```
output = open('output.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding='iso_8859_1')
```

The input that I give to the file is from OpenAI's API.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text

Comment: Can you provide an example? How about `utf-8`

Comment: @LuisAlejandroVargasRamos Well, this would be helpful if I am trying to determine the type of encoding. But I think that the  encodings of my languages are different, resulting in some output being messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Just use utf-8:

```
output = open('output.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I did. But the problem is that the output becomes more messed up, giving me weird signs.

Comment: This is some example output.

Comment: @OmarZayed: just set the other editors to UTF-8. All of them should be able to cope with UTF-8 which it is in fact the standard encoding now. On Windows you may want to use UTF-8 with bon so `'utf-8-sig'` as Python encoding string. It mess up other tools.

Answer (score -1):

I don´t know if this is valid for german, but its valid for spanish. Try "latin1" in the encoding

Hope it helps

Comment: This is some example output from the file. ؟Cَmo estلs?

Comment: I get an arabic in there for some reason.

Comment: Latin-1 is just an alias for ISO-8859-1

Comment: Can you write a couple of lines of your file, that way I can try with the encoding

Comment: besides the encoding specified in the line opening the file. Can you try to add this before opening the file? os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "latin1"