# How to open a textfile in python on windows with the correct encoding?

Tags: python, windows, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

I am aware that [correctly determining the encoding of text is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436299/7465516).
I notice however, that programs such as notepad can correctly read a file encoded in utf-8, and I want to do the same in python.

`open` can not do it, it is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in python3.11 to use the systems local encoding as default, which is 'cp1252' on my machine, so the behaviour does not depend on any BOM or other magic that might be in the file or its metadata.

The following code acts the same on python-versions 3.7, 3.10 and 3.11 (which is all that I tried):

```py
fname = "tmpWindowsOut.txt"
with open(fname, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    # if encoding wasn't specified in `open` this fails with the infamous 
    # UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03b2' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>
    f.write("βKHα") 

with open(fname, "r") as f:
    print(f.read()) # prints Î²KHÎ±

# opening the file with notepad shows the correct output
```

I know I can correctly read the file by passing the encoding-parameter to the other `open`-call, the question is not how to read a file that is known to be encoded in `utf-8`. The question is how to either:

1. do the `read`-portion correctly *without* specifying the encoding
2. do the `write`-portion in a way that makes No.1 easier (or even just possible)

Comment: Use the trick used by HTML: open is as 'utf-8' (explicitly), and if it fails use the default system encoding, else open with cp437 (or system + escape errors). All text is shifting to UTF-8, so it is a nice and easy default. If you want more, check about UTF-16 and UTF-32 (expect a BOM at beginning).

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi that seems to be a good approach in general but too hard to implement in a few lines, since it is not sufficient to check for exceptions - in the example above, the read does not fail but produce nonsense. So you need to detect nonsense. I will look for a library, I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: def my_open(...): try ret=open(, encoding='utf-8'): except UnicodeError: ret = open() return ret;

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi no, that does not work. Reading a file with the wrong encoding does not reliably produce an excepion - it often results in bad data. Like the example in my question: reading "βKHα" in a wrong way yields "Î²KHÎ±"

Comment: a library would need to detect that "Î²KHÎ±" is unlikely to have a real meaning. Which is difficult enough for normal human language but extra-difficult here, because you won't find the real text "βKHα" in a dictionary either, it has meaning in a very special engineering context.

Comment: As I said: I explain the HTML method: you try UTF-8. It if it is invalid (because UTF-8 has various requirements), you use local encoding. It is just a simple method which works well often. If you need to distinguish 8-bit encodings, there is no reliable way. But it is very seldom to decode a non UTF-8 file as valid UTF-8, and the alternate encoding is often just system or cp1252: Just a simple way it works most of the time. If you have old text files you are out of luck. But my method is reliable to find it is it UTF-8 (and it has a good fallback)

Comment: If you're going to create a file with a specific encoding then you need to open that file with the same encoding. This also makes your code portable. For example, your code behaves as you would hope on macOS because that platform's default encoding is UTF-8. You should note the proposition in PEP 686 that UTF-8 should be the default encoding on all platforms