# python reading text file with prefixing FF FE bytes

Tags: python, encoding

I have got a file, which can be opened in VSCode editor as a normal text file. But if I try to read it in Python:

```py
with open("file.ass") as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
       ...
```

it will throw an exception:

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

If I try to open it with binary mode, the first a few bytes read like:

```py
f = open("file.ass", "rb")
b = f.read()
print(b[:50])

Out[36]: b'\xff\xfe[\x00S\x00c\x00r\x00i\x00p\x00t\x00 \x00I\x00n\x00f\x00o\x00]\x00\r\x00\n\x00;\x00 \x00S\x00c\x00r\x00i\x00p\x00t\x00 \x00'
```

If I do `decode('utf-16')`, I can see the correct characters.

```py
b[:50].decode('utf-16')
Out[58]: '[Script Info]\r\n; Script '
```

But I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to handle such files like a normal text files. In another word, how could I know if I need to do `decode('utf-16')` and use `readlines()` like reading a normal text file? Thanks.

Comment: There is no "normal" text file. You must always know the encoding. Python uses a standard encoding if you do not specify one. Often this is UTF-8 (and this is compatible with ASCII).

Comment: Simply use `open("file.ass", encoding="utf-16")`.

Comment: There is no universal way to know a text file encoding. In your case, the file starts with a Byte Order Mark (BOM) which was Mirosoft's way of trying to fight its way out of its ill-fated decision to use UTF-16 for file encodings. You can use the `chardet` module to guess encodings. That's great for BOM files but more risky when it tries to guess old-style microsoft code page files.

Comment: @mkrieger1 the question is how to know whether to use utf-16 or some other encoding.

Comment: as an aside, don't do `for line in f.readlines():`. Pretty much, you should never use `.readlines`. The above should just for `for line in f:`... and if you need a list of lines from the whole file, just use `lines = list(f)`

Comment: The FF FE sequence is a UTF-16 Byte-Order Marker.  Windows adds that when it writes a UTF-16 file.  If you use `encoding="utf-16"` when you open, Python will suck up that word.

Comment: tools like `chardet` can detect encoding based upon magic starting bytes and heuristics, but it's not a perfect solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/how-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `encoding` when opening the file.

```
with open("file.ass", encoding='utf-16') as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
       ...
```

As you said that your file opens in VSCode you can check the guessed encoding of the file at the bottom of your VSCode:
[image: VSCod showing encoding with UTF-8]

You can then use the same encoding with Python.

Note that VSCode uses `"files.autoGuessEncoding":true` (you can check it in the settings). So that's why you have it reading your file as a "normal text".