# Difference between open and codecs.open in Python

Tags: python, unicode, codec

There are two ways to open a text file in Python:

```
f = open(filename)
```

And

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8")
```

When is `codecs.open` preferable to `open`?

Comment: Note that `codecs.open()` is obsolete in 3.x, since `open()` gains an `encoding` argument.

Comment: There's also a 3rd way (in Python 2.x at least): `f = file(filename)'

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is there any link that `codecs.open()` is obsolete? I don't think this in python3 docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html

Comment: @varela: the Python documentation page you mentioned says: "the builtin open() and the associated io module are the recommended approach for working with encoded text files"

Comment: What about `import io; io.open(...)` ?

Answer (score 95):

Since Python 2.6, a good practice is to use `io.open()`, which also takes an `encoding` argument, like the now obsolete `codecs.open()`. In Python 3, `io.open` is an alias for the `open()` built-in. So `io.open()` works in Python 2.6 and all later versions, including Python 3.4. See docs: http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/io.html

Now, for the original question: when reading **text** (including "plain text", HTML, XML and JSON) in Python 2 you should **always** use `io.open()` with an explicit encoding, or `open()` with an explicit encoding in Python 3. Doing so means you get correctly decoded Unicode, or get an error right off the bat, making it much easier to debug.

Pure ASCII "plain text" is a myth from the distant past. Proper English text uses curly quotes, em-dashes, bullets, € (euro signs) and even diaeresis (¨). Don't be naïve! (And let's not forget the Façade design pattern!)

Because pure ASCII is not a real option, `open()` without an explicit encoding is **only** useful to read **binary** files.

Comment: @ForeverWintr The answer is pretty clearly in there: use `io.open()` for text, and `open()` only for binary. The implication is that `codecs.open()` is not preferred at all.

Comment: @Bdoserror, There is *an* answer in there, clearly, but it's not an answer to the question that was asked. The question was about the difference between `open` and `codecs.open`, and specifically when the latter is preferable to the former. An answer that doesn't so much as mention `codecs.open` can't answer that question.

Comment: @ForeverWintr If the the OP asked the _wrong_ question (i.e. with the assumption that `codecs.open()` was correct to use) then there is no "correct" answer about when to use it. The answer is to use `io.open()` instead. It's like if I ask "when should I use a wrench to drive a nail into a wall?". The right answer is "use a hammer".

Comment: sometimes there is an unspoken question. In this one it is, "I don't know what `codecs.open` is for if `open` seems to do the same thing! What is it?" -- many thanks for explaining both!

Answer (score 23):

Personally, I *always* use `codecs.open` unless there's a clear identified need to use `open`**.  The reason is that there's been so many times when I've been bitten by having utf-8 input sneak into my programs.  "Oh, I just know it'll always be ascii" tends to be an assumption that gets broken often.

Assuming 'utf-8' as the default encoding tends to be a safer default choice in my experience, since ASCII can be treated as UTF-8, but the converse is not true.  And in those cases when I truly do *know* that the input is ASCII, then I still do `codecs.open` as I'm a firm believer in ["explicit is better than implicit"](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

** - in Python 2.x, as the comment on the question states in Python 3 `open` replaces `codecs.open`

Comment: what I don't really get is why `open` sometimes can handle very well the UTF-8 encoded non-latin characters of the unicode set, and sometimes it fails miserabily ...

Comment: This makes sense to me. `io.open` does not take an encoding param from what I can see in python 2.7.5

Comment: @radtek, you are right that this is undocumented; however (at least in 2.7.12) `io.open` accepts `encoding` and `newline` parameters and interprets them as Python 3 does. Unlike `codecs.open`, a file opened with `io.open` will raise `TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str` even in Python 2.7 if you attempt to write `str` (`bytes`) to it. A file opened with `codecs.open` will instead attempt implicit conversion to `unicode`, often leading to confusing `UnicodeDecodeError`s.

Answer (score 12):

In Python 2 there are unicode strings and bytestrings. If you just use bytestrings, you can read/write to a file opened with `open()` just fine. After all, the strings are just bytes.

The problem comes when, say, you have a unicode string and you do the following:

```
>>> example = u'Μου αρέσει Ελληνικά'
>>> open('sample.txt', 'w').write(example)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So here obviously you either explicitly encode your unicode string in utf-8 or you use `codecs.open` to do it for you transparently.

If you're only ever using bytestrings then no problems:

```
>>> example = 'Μου αρέσει Ελληνικά'
>>> open('sample.txt', 'w').write(example)
>>>
```

It gets more involved than this because when you concatenate a unicode and bytestring string with the `+` operator you get a unicode string. Easy to get bitten by that one.

Also `codecs.open` doesn't like bytestrings with non-ASCII chars being passed in:

```
codecs.open('test', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write('Μου αρέσει')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 691, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The advice about strings for input/ouput is normally "convert to unicode as early as possible and back to bytestrings as late as possible". Using `codecs.open` allows you to do the latter very easily.

Just be careful that you are giving it unicode strings and not bytestrings that may have non-ASCII characters.

Comment: Can you explain your second example? It appears to be identical to your first example, so why would the result be any different?

Comment: Note the use of the `u''` in the first example. This means I created a unicode string, not a bytestring. This is the difference between the two examples. In the second example I am creating a bytestring and writing out one of those to a file is just fine. A unicode string is not fine if you're using characters outside of ASCII.

Answer (score 7):

`codecs.open`, i suppose, is just a remnant from the `Python 2` days when the built-in open had a much simpler interface and fewer capabilities. In Python 2, built-in `open` doesn't take an encoding argument, so if you want to use something other than binary mode or the default encoding, codecs.open was supposed to be used.

In `Python 2.6`, the io module came to the aid to make things a bit simpler.
According to the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html)

```
New in version 2.6.

The io module provides the Python interfaces to stream handling.
Under Python 2.x, this is proposed as an alternative to the
built-in file object, but in Python 3.x it is the default
interface to access files and streams.
```

Having said that, the only use i can think of `codecs.open` in the current scenario is for the backward compatibility. In all other scenarios (unless you are using Python < 2.6) it is preferable to use `io.open`. Also in `Python 3.x` `io.open` is the same as `built-in open`

**Note:**

There is a syntactical difference between `codecs.open` and `io.open` as well.

`codecs.open`:

```
open(filename, mode='rb', encoding=None, errors='strict', buffering=1)
```

`io.open`:

```
open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None,
     errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)
```

Comment: Not only `codecs.open` and `io.open` differ in terms of syntax, they return objects of different type. Also `codecs.open` always works with files in binary mode.

Answer (score 5):

When you need to open a file that has a certain encoding, you would use the `codecs` module.

Comment: I guess all the text files have a certain encoding, somehow (:

Answer (score 5):

- When you want to load a binary file, use
  `f = io.open(filename, 'b')`.
- For opening a text file, always use `f = io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8')` with explicit encoding.

In **python 3** however `open` does the same thing as `io.open` and can be used instead.

> **Note:** `codecs.open` is planned to become [deprecated](https://bugs.python.org/issue8796) and replaced by [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) after its introduction in **python 2.6**. I would only use it if code needs to be compatible with earlier python versions. For more information on codecs and unicode in python see the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: 1. Why can't I open a file in binary mode with `io.open` or `codecs.open`? 2. `codecs.open` is not deprecated yet, read the discussion on the page you linked to.

Comment: Good points!
1. You can use either, but I would again advice against codecs.open unless you're on python 2.5 or older.
2. I updated my answer to reflect that the deprecation did not take place immediately, but rather in the future.

Answer (score 2):

When you're working with text files and want transparent encoding and decoding into Unicode objects.