# Can't read string from csv file

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I'm reading a utf8 encoded csv file with python

```
f = open('test.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(f)
r = reader.next()
r[10]
```

which returns

```
'\xc3\x9altima actualizaci\xc3\xb3n del ejercicio 2014: 27 Abril 2014.'
```

That should be 'Última actualización del ...'

I'm just wondering how is that data encoded (multy byte perhaps?) and how can I convert it to a normal string with the following content: 'Última actualización del ...'

I tried with:

```
r[10].decode('utf8')
```

but I got

```
u'\xdaltima actualizaci\xf3n del ejercicio 2014: 27 Abril 2014.'
```

Comment: Which version of python are you using? Which IDE? Have you read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)?

Comment: This is a very good read, It will explain what is going on. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('test.csv', 'r',  'utf-8') as f:
    ...
```

Similar answer:
[Difference between open and codecs.open in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250744/difference-between-open-and-codecs-open-in-python)