# Difference between io.open vs open in python

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, io, python-2.x

In the past, there's `codecs` which got replaced by `io`. Although it seems like it's more advisable to use `io.open`, most introductory python classes still teaches `open`.

There's a question with [Difference between open and codecs.open in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250744/difference-between-open-and-codecs-open-in-python) but **is `open` a mere duck-type of `io.open`?**

**If not, why is it better to use `io.open`? And why is it easier to teach with `open`?**

In this post (http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/681909/), Steven DAprano says that the built in `open` is using the `io.open` in the backend. **So should we all refactored our code to use `open` instead of `io.open`?**

**Other than backward compatibility for py2.x, are there any reason to use `io.open` instead of `open` in py3.0?**

Comment: Check out `help(open)` and you'll see that it's the same as `io.open()` - even the heading says `Help on built-in function open in module io`, so in other words, there is no reason to use `io.open()` if you're writing a program in Python 3.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, `io.open` is only for backwards compatibility right? If so, I should start changing all the class materials for `python3` =)

Comment: Yes, probably. It makes porting from 2.x to 3.x easier, but if you're starting out with 3.x, there's no need to make this more complicated.

Comment: What brought me to this post: This is relevant for __ruff__ rule **UP020** (open-alias; Use builtin open) which is based on [`pyupgrade`](https://pypi.org/project/pyupgrade/)'s replacement of `io.open()` with `open()` in line with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Situation in Python3 according to the docs:

> `io.open(file, *[options]*)`
>
> This is an alias for the builtin open() function.

and

> **While the builtin open() and the associated io module are the
>   recommended approach** for working with encoded text files, this module
>   *[i.e. codecs]* provides additional utility functions and classes that
>   allow the use of a wider range of codecs when working with binary
>   files

(bold and italics are my edits)