# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I'm currently writing a program which utilizes the Python NLTK library to determine whether a review is positive or negative. When trying to tokenize and store each word in an array, I keep getting the above error. The lines of code before and up to the error lines are:

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

...

short_pos = open("reviews/pos_reviews.txt", "r").read()
short_neg = open("reviews/neg_reviews.txt", "r").read()

documents = []

for r in short_pos.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (r, "pos") )

for r in short_neg.split('\n'):
    documents.append( (r, "neg") )

all_words = []

short_pos_words = word_tokenize(short_pos)
short_neg_words = word_tokenize(short_neg)
```

The second to last line is where it's saying I have an error. If I comment out that line, the error appears on the following line. I'm not sure where this error would arise, as I didn't think I was working with unicode at all. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @candied_orange my code is running on v2.7.15

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.7, try to use `io` module to specify file encoding, see [Difference between io.open vs open in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891373/difference-between-io-open-vs-open-in-python)

Also, context manager is your friend (i.e. `with ... as ...`), esp. when it comes to I/O https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/

```
import io

from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

documents = []

with io.open("reviews/pos_reviews.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as fin:
    for line in fin:
        documents.append((line.strip(), "pos"))
```