# Error in writing Unicode charters using python

Tags: python

I am trying to write unicode char in to text file using the following python code

```
with codecs.open("File.txt", mode='wb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(str(u'\u6587\u5b66\u5b66\u58eb 2005\u5e743\u6708\uff1a \u83b7\u5927\u5b66\u82f1\u8bed\u516d\u7ea7\u8bc1\u4e66'))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
```

I am getting the following error

**'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)**

Please help me in resolving this issue

Comment: Why are you opening the file in binary mode if you want to write unicode?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to write text, then you should probably open the file in text (and not binary) mode.

Change `mode='wb'` to `mode='w'` (if you want to create a new file or wipe clean an existing file) or `mode='a'` (if you want to append to an existing file):

```
with codecs.open("File.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    ...
```

In `python 3.x` you can just use [`open()` instead of `codecs.open()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250744/difference-between-open-and-codecs-open-in-python), like this:

```
with open("File.txt", mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    ...
```