# Invalid continuation byte while reading .txt file

Tags: python, python-unicode, dictionary-attack

I'm getting this error in my python code:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 5884: invalid continuation byte

The script is for a dictionary attack using the Crackstation dictionary. I'm trying to make this for fun, but there's a problem when I try to iterate through the items in the dictionary.

```
pass_file = open(pass_doc, 'r')

for word in pass_file:
```

`pass_doc` is a `.txt` file, NOT `.csv`. Does it have to be `.csv`?

I've tried using `load_text()` instead of `open()`, but all I want is a simple list of items.  What should happen is the code runs through all the items in the dictionary, stored in a list, and I don't know really what's wrong.

Comment: You need to pass an `encoding=` parameter to the `open()` call that matches the actual encoding of the file.  (You haven't supplied enough information for us to tell what that encoding might be.)

Comment: `utf-8` is the default encoding method assumed by `open`; your file is *not* UTF-8-encoded.

Comment: Are there any characters other than normal U.S. Keyboard chars?

Comment: Thanks everyone i just came back to the project a simply saved a UTF-8 version. When i first tried this i had no idea that it wasnt already!

Answer (score -2):

Make your text file encoded as utf-8 when saving it. If you want to keep the current encoding,
try this:

```
import codecs
BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
with codecs.open(sourceFileName, "r", "your-source-encoding") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open(targetFileName, "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)
```

This question might also help: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)

Comment: If you think my answer isn't very good, please suggest a way that I can improve it.

Comment: There isn't really a way to improve this – it's just wrong. `open(foo)` is exactly the same as `open(foo, 'r')`, so this isn't a solution. On top of an obvious syntax error the code suggests an anti-pattern – `data = f.readlines()` *needlessly* pulls the entire file into memory and keeps it there.

Comment: This code is no way fixes the problem.  It's just another way of doing the same wrong thing.

Comment: Alright, I have changed the code in a way that it can help.

Comment: Why `codecs.open()` instead of the regular `open()`?

Comment: @John Gordon, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250744/difference-between-open-and-codecs-open-in-python

Comment: That Q&A is rather outdated and focuses on Python 2 but still states multiple times that in Python 3, the plain `open` is appropriate.

Comment: I prefer to use that in case someone is using python 2.