# Python Flask, how to set 'Content-Type' for static files (js)?

Tags: python, flask, content-type

For my Flask app I use 'windows-1251' encoding. To draw a template I set 'Content-Type' as follows:

```
from flask.helpers import make_response

def render_tmpl_dummy():
    response = make_response("Some Russian text here")
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=windows-1251'
    return response
```

And all fine here. But my static js-files also in 'windows-1251'. So, is there any way to set `'Content-Type=application/x-javascript; charset=windows-1251'` for all static files? 
(PS: I do not want to convert them to UTF-8 manually in advance, this method is not suitable for me)

Comment: no offense, but WHY Win1251?

Comment: Legacy code ... the parent project is already 5+ years with win1251

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to give all files with a custom [extension](https://jsonlines.org/#conventions) in the static folder a custom [MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690624/json-lines-mime-type#comment122920211_67807011) on the development server:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    CUSTOM_FILE_EXTENSION = '.jsonl'
    CUSTOM_MIME_TYPE = 'application/jsonl+json'

    @flask_app.route(flask_app.static_url_path + '/' + '<path:path>' + CUSTOM_FILE_EXTENSION)
    def jsonl_mime_type(path):
        return flask.send_from_directory(
            directory=flask_app.static_folder,
            path=path + CUSTOM_FILE_EXTENSION,
            mimetype=CUSTOM_MIME_TYPE
        )
```

In effect, I simply reinvented the Flask static web server, which apparently consists of a [single call](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/660994efc761efdfd49ca442b73f6712dc77b6cf/src/flask/app.py#L510) to add_url_rule() in the Flask constructor:

```
        self.add_url_rule(
            f"{self.static_url_path}/<path:filename>",
            endpoint="static",
            host=static_host,
            view_func=lambda **kw: self_ref().send_static_file(**kw),
        )
```

I went to all this trouble so the development server behaved more like production, where Apache has a [gentler](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#AddType) way to set MIME type.

Answer (score -1):

Your static files shouldn't be served by the web server other than in development, so converting the file encoding is the **correct** method.

If your reason for not converting the files first is due to volume, see [How to convert a file to utf-8 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python) to see how to automate it.

Comment: It makes me uncomfortable to convert files, because I get them from the parent project. In fact, this project - it cut-off-part of parent large project, with a small specific task. That is why I use Flask and its web server for "production".

Comment: This belongs as a comment. It offers a possible solution to an alternative question, and with more certainty than it merits.