# JSON lines Mime type

Tags: json, jsonlines

I want to know what Content-Type to set for JSON lines (http://jsonlines.org/)?

I tried searching. Its not really application/json as the entire content is not JSON (each line is).

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

JSON lines is supported by [some AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-inference.html#cm-batch) and they use `application/jsonlines` content type.

Comment: `application/jsonlines+json` <-- the [json suffix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type#Suffix) is technically a lie, but it encourages Chrome to display the file as text/plain. Otherwise it downloads as octet/stream.

Comment: application/jsonlines helps directly with respect to AWS Sagemaker DeepAR Batch Transform.

Answer (score 8):

As per https://github.com/wardi/jsonlines/issues/9, there is no official mime type, but a convention of application/x-ndjson. Or application/x-jsonlines. Note that this issue has been sitting there since 2015, which might suggest that jsonlines is not exactly catching fire.

Comment: Thanks, any other suggestion for storing structured data in a file?

Comment: @codesalsa At the risk of self-promotion, I wrote a python package called jsv (json separated values) meant to store structured data with the expressiveness of json lines, but the compactness of csv. It is available here: https://pypi.org/project/jsv/. Very early stages on this idea.

Comment: The jsonlines format is widely used, just not by name (because it's such an obvious idea) - JSON based log formats (such as in Docker, JournalD, etc.), streaming JSON apis, etc.

Answer (score 6):

I have the server return `text/plain; charset=utf8` for JSON Lines files. As @bmargulies says, `application/x-ndjson` has limited support. At least with `text/plain` users can see the data in their browser (rather than being shown a download/save as dialog). Setting the charset explicitly prevents random "corruption" by (un)helpful user agents.

Answer (score 0):

At https://jsonlines.org/ they suggest using "application/jsonl" but it is still not standardized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).