# Override encoding of xml reader in Python

Tags: python, xml, encoding

I am reading from xml files into Python with the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(file_name)
```

For some reason the source i am reading from appears to have the incorrect encoding specified in the file (it is correct for 10 years of the data that I am reading from, and then suddenly i get problems for subsequent files).

Specifically i get the following error raised:

`xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: encoding specified in XML declaration is incorrect: line 1, column 30`

I think the data is encoding in `UTF-8`, however the encoding specified in the file is `UTF-16` [the first line of the file is `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16'?>`] - when i manually change the file text to say `UTF-8` i do not get an error raised, and as far as i can tell, it appears to be reading everything correctly.

How do you override the xml reader so that it treats the encoding as `UTF-8`, and ignores what is specified within the file?

Comment: Open the  file manually, specify the encoding and pass the string to fromstring. You can try chardet to find out the actual encoding https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet

Comment: Isn't this thread of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796238/reading-xml-header-encoding