# Corrupted Hebrew: saved as ansi - covert back to UTF-8

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, hebrew, codepages

I suspect some data has been saved (on windows machines) as ANSI.
Therefore, the original Hebrew characters got lost and what we see is stuff like
`ùéôåãé äòéø`.

Is the information lost or is there a possibility to map back the characters, knowing that the original text was Hebrew?

Answer (score 1):

The information is probably not lost, or at most partially lost. If you want to use Python:

```
import codecs
BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
with codecs.open("input.txt", "r", "windows-1255") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open("output.txt", "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
               break
            targetFile.write(contents)
```

Stolen and adapted from [How to convert a file to utf-8 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python)

You can also use an external tool, like iconv:

```
iconv -f windows-1255 -t utf-8 input.txt > output.txt
```

Iconv is available in most Linux distibutions, in Cygwin, and on other platforms.

If the file got double-mangled, you may need to do something like this:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1252 input.txt > tmp.txt
iconv -f windows-1255 -t utf-8 tmp.txt > output.txt
```

but the chances that this kind of stuff happened are minuscule.

Comment: It might be a dedicated Hebrew code page rather than UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

i had a very similar problem where the text look equally corrupted.
The [online-decoder](https://www.online-decoder.com/he/ei) told me that for some reason the text got encoded with `iso-8859-1` instead of `iso-8859-8`

```
text.encode("iso-8859-1").decode("iso-8859-8")
```