# How re-write pre-existing text file as utf-8 in a separate file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, encode

I'm attempting to write a program where the code reads from a pre-existing text file, and then writes the text in that file as utf-8 in a new text file. How would I go about doing this? My apologies I am extremely new to python and I'm unaware of any modules that could help accomplish this task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python

Comment: If you're new to Python, don't board a sinking ship – learn Python 3, not 2.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out this question asked previously: [How to convert a file to utf-8 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python)

But to summarize you should see the `codecs` library and particularly `codecs.open()` which allows specification of a file type.