# UTF-8 to EBCDIC using iconv in Python-script on USS

Tags: python-2.7, mainframe, zos

I am trying to convert utf-8 files from a directory listing on USS into ebcdic files BEFORE getting them into z/OS datasets.

Using a helper function which I found on stackoverflow (thanks for this!) I can issue shell-commands from within the python script:

```
def r(cmd_line): 
     return Popen(cmd_line.split(), stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

With this I can allocate and populate mainframe datasets from USS-files, using

```
 r("tso alloc DSNAME(...) etc.")    # to allocate a mainframe DS and
 r("tso oget ...")                  # to populate the mainframe DS
```

However: some files need to be converted first, which in a shellscript I would simply code with

> iconv -f UTF-8 -t IBM-1141 $utf8_file > $ebcdic_file

and I am totally at a loss of how to do this in python (2.7)?

Can't ask anybody in my shop since python was newly installed and I am currently the only one interested in it. Anyone an idea? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use iconv?

Comment: @meat: thanks, that looks good; although that runs me into a probable encoding issue with the sourcefile: 
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x78 in position 2: invalid continuation byte

Comment: @ Kevin: what would be an alternative way?

Comment: If it cannot decode it and the file _looks_ like it is in UTF-8 it might be ISO-8859-1. You can also consider using file tagging which would automatically convert the file when it is opened.

Comment: tried out the following, but the print output is 0 - 

`sourceFileName = "/u/arb07/myscripts/python/utf8file" `
`targetFileName = "/u/arb07/myscripts/python/ebcdicfile" `

How can I redirect the converted file from stdout to a file?

Comment: OK, thanks everybody! I think I got it: if I use a file-object and redirect `stdout=myTargetFile` in subprocess.call() I do get a converted file.

Answer (score 0):

Although not in the true spirit of python, you can do what you want by wrapping USS commands in a python script. Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/env python

from cStringIO import StringIO
import os
import sys

def r(cmd):
    import subprocess
    return subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

def allocate_dataset(dsName):
    name = "'" + dsName + "'"
    out = r(['/bin/tso', 'alloc',  'ds(' + name + ')',  'space(6000 2000)',  'track', 'lrecl(80)',
             'dsntype(library)', 'blksize(3200)',  'recfm(f b)',  'dir(2)',  'new'])
    for line in out.split():
        print line

def not_allocated(dsName):
    name = "'" + dsName + "'"
    out = r(['/bin/tsocmd', 'listds ' + name])
    for line in out.split():
        if "NOT IN CATALOG" in out:
            return True
    return False

def ascii_to_ebcdic(from_codepage, to_codepage, fileName):
    os.system('iconv -f' + from_codepage + ' -t' + to_codepage + ' <' + fileName + ' >ebcdic_' + fileName)

def copy_to_dataset(fileName, dsName, memberName):
    dsn = "//'" + dsName + '(' + memberName + ")'"
    os.system('cp -T ' + fileName + ' "' + dsn + '"')

def main():
    dsName = "HLQ.MY.PYTHON"
    if not_allocated(dsName):
        print("Allocating '" + dsName + "' data set")
        allocate_dataset(dsName)
    ascii_to_ebcdic("UTF-8", "IBM-1047", "test.txt")
    copy_to_dataset("ebcdic_test.txt", "HLQ.MY.PYTHON", "TXT")
    member = "//'HLQ.MY.PYTHON(TXT)'"
    os.system('cat -v "' + member + '"')

main()
```

Comment: that was pretty nifty! Thanks for the example - esp. for showing how quoting within quoting would work **(' " some var " ')**. It's really tedious trying to figure that out by trial and error.  ;-)